# How to remove accents and tilde in a C++ std::string

Tags: c++, string, text, str-replace

I have a problem with a string in C++ which has several words in Spanish. This means that I have a lot of words with accents and tildes. I want to replace them for their not accented counterparts. Example: I want to replace this word: "había" for habia. I tried replace it directly but with replace method of string class but I could not get that to work.

I'm using this code:

```
for (it= dictionary.begin(); it != dictionary.end(); it++)
{
    strMine=(it->first);
    found=toReplace.find_first_of(strMine);
    while (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        strAux=(it->second);
        toReplace.erase(found,strMine.length());
        toReplace.insert(found,strAux);
        found=toReplace.find_first_of(strMine,found+1);
    }
}
```

Where `dictionary` is a map like this (with more entries):

```
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("á","a") );
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("é","e") );
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("í","i") );
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("ó","o") );
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("ú","u") );
dictionary.insert ( std::pair<std::string,std::string>("ñ","n") );
```

and `toReplace` strings is:

```
std::string toReplace="á-é-í-ó-ú-ñ-á-é-í-ó-ú-ñ";
```

I obviously must be missing something. I can't figure it out.
Is there any library I can use?.

Thanks,

Comment: You should add the platform you are targeting (Windows, Linux, etc.), and the encoding you are targeting (UTF-8, UTF-16, whatever). For example, your "á" is glyph E1, which translates 'á' on USO-8859-1 char, L'á' on UTF-16 wchar_t, but "Ã¡" (yes, two chars) on UTF-8

Comment: Sorry... By the time I got back to your post (from searching on Unicode.org) and validated the comment, you did answer...

Comment: This is a duplicate of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140422/how-do-i-translate-8bit-characters-into-7bit-characters-ie-220-to-u">
How do I translate 8bit characters into 7bit characters? (i.e. Ü to U)
</a>.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, this is a really bad idea: you’re mangling somebody’s language by removing letters. Although the extra dots in words like “naïve” seem superfluous to people who only speak English, there are literally thousands of writing systems in the world in which such distinctions are very important. Writing software to mutilate someone’s speech puts you squarely on the wrong side of the tension between using computers as means to broaden the realm of human expression vs. tools of oppression.

What is the reason you’re trying to do this? Is something further down the line choking on the accents? Many people would love to help you solve that.

That said, libicu can do this for you. Open the [transform demo](http://www.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit); copy and paste your Spanish text into the “Input” box; enter

```
NFD; [:M:] remove; NFC
```

as “Compound 1” and click transform.

(With help from slide 9 of [Unicode Transforms in ICU](http://macchiato.com/slides/icu_transforms.pdf). Slides 29-30 show how to use the API.)

Comment: Well, I am from Argentina which is a spanish speaking country, so I'm pretty covered there with the first part.Let me give more details in an answer below.

Comment: Right on! Accents and tildes are not there to be cute; chopping them off WILL change the meaning of the text. "Habia" is not a word but "había" is. "Carácter" is 'personality'; a "caracter" is a printed symbol. "Cana" is a white hair; "Caña" is a cane. "Peso" is a noun. "Pesó" is a verb.

Comment: By the way. I found this page that explains how to use the ICU Transliterator:

http://www.markcmusic.com/blog/2008/08/28/using-the-icu4c-transliterator/

Comment: While that's true in theory, in practice, many Spanish speakers don't bother to use accents or just get them wrogn (IM comes to mind) and the meaning is still clear. It's like its/it's, they're/their, etc in English. Using them wrong shows a bit of negligence but rarely causes misunderstanding.

Comment: In Dutch, accents are used for emphasis. "een" is Dutch for "an" or "one", as in "een appel".  But if you want to stress _precisely_ one, you'd add accents: "één appel"

Comment: This is a pretty unusual take. Removing accents can be useful when implementing a search feature, where someone who might not know how to type accents might be searching through something that has accents. Removing accents can also be useful when dealing with ancient programs that *nobody* is willing to "help" with. Whitaker's words, a Latin dictionary, does not support letters with macrons in them, since it is a very old program and macrons are not needed to read Latin and they didn't even exist until 1645.

Answer (score 35):

I disagree with the currently "approved" answer. The question makes perfect sense when you are indexing text. Like case-insensitive search, accent-insensitive search is a good idea. "naïve" matches "Naïve" matches "naive" matches "NAİVE" (you *do* know that an uppercase i is İ in Turkish? That's why you ignore accents)

Now, the best algorithm is hinted at the approved answer: Use NKD (decomposition) to decompose accented letters into the base letter and a seperate accent, and then remove all accents.

There is little point in the re-composition afterwards, though. You removed most sequences which would change, and the others are for all intents and purposes identical anyway. WHat's the difference between æ in NKC and æ in NKD?

Comment: your theory falls apart in german. "bär" (bear) will compare to "baer" (bear) but not to "bar" (bar).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Unicode decomposition of bär gives ba"r (using an extra codepoint for the umlaut), not baer. Remmeber that Unicode decomposition is locale-independent. ä = ae is a German, but not e.g. a Dutch decomposition.

Comment: I think you mean 'İ', not 'Ï' for a capital 'i'.

Comment: Maybe you could point to some definition of those NKC / NKD stuff?

Answer (score 2):

I definitely think you should look into the root of the problem.  That is, look for a solution that will allow you to support characters encoded in Unicode or for the user's locale.

That being said, your problem is that you're dealing with multi-character strings.  There is `std::wstring` but I'm not sure I'd use that.  For one thing, wide characters aren't meant to handle variable width encodings.  This hole goes deep, so I'll leave it at that.

Now, as for the rest of your code, it is error prone because you mix the looping logic with translation logic.  Thus, at least two kinds of bugs can occur:  translation bugs and looping bugs.  Do use the STL, it can help you a lot with the looping part.

The following is a rough solution for replacing characters in a string.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include "translate_characters.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text;
    cin.unsetf(ios::skipws);
    transform(istream_iterator<char>(cin), istream_iterator<char>(),
              inserter(text, text.end()), translate_characters());
    cout << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**translate_characters.h**:

```
#ifndef TRANSLATE_CHARACTERS_H
#define TRANSLATE_CHARACTERS_H

#include <functional>
#include <map>

class translate_characters : public std::unary_function<const char,char> {
public:
    translate_characters();
    char operator()(const char c);

private:
    std::map<char, char> characters_map;
};

#endif // TRANSLATE_CHARACTERS_H
```

**translate_characters.cpp**:

```
#include "translate_characters.h"

using namespace std;

translate_characters::translate_characters()
{
    characters_map.insert(make_pair('e', 'a'));
}

char translate_characters::operator()(const char c)
{
    map<char, char>::const_iterator translation_pos(characters_map.find(c));
    if( translation_pos == characters_map.end() )
        return c;
    return translation_pos->second;
}
```

Comment: Your are mapping <char,char>. but utf-8 "ñ" (for example) is not (equivalent to) a char (but rather a 2-bytes thing actually). This is a nice on-the-fly technique, but it's much more complicated than that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the boost (http://www.boost.org/) library.

It has a regexp library, which you could use.
In addition it has a specific library that has some functions for string manipulation ([link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html)) including replace.

Answer (score 0):

I could not link the ICU libraries but I still think it's the best solution. As I need this program to be functional as soon as possible I made a little program (that I have to improve) and I'm going to use that. Thank you all for for suggestions and answers.

Here's the code I'm gonna use:

```
for (it= dictionary.begin(); it != dictionary.end(); it++)
{
    strMine=(it->first);
    found=toReplace.find(strMine);
    while (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        strAux=(it->second);
        toReplace.erase(found,2);
        toReplace.insert(found,strAux);
        found=toReplace.find(strMine,found+1);
    }
}
```

I will change it next time I have to turn my program in for correction (in about 6 weeks).

Answer (score -1):

If you can (if you're running Unix), I suggest using the [`tr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html) facility for this: it's custom-built for this purpose. Remember, no code == no buggy code. :-)

Edit: Sorry, you're right, `tr` doesn't seem to work. How about `sed`? It's a pretty stupid script I've written, but it works for me.

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/á/a/g;
s/é/e/g;
s/í/i/g;
s/ó/o/g;
s/ú/u/g;
s/ñ/n/g;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using std::wstring instead of std::string. UTF-16 should work (as opposed to ASCII).

Answer (score -2):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// Replace any accent and foreign character by their ASCII equivalent.
    /// In other words, convert a string to an ASCII-complient string.
    /// 
    /// This also get rid of special hidden character, like EOF, NUL, TAB and other '\0', except \n\r
    /// 
    /// Tests with accents and foreign characters:
    /// Before: "äæǽaeöœoeüueÄAeÜUeÖOeÀÁÂÃÄÅǺĀĂĄǍΑΆẢẠẦẪẨẬẰẮẴẲẶАAàáâãåǻāăąǎªαάảạầấẫẩậằắẵẳặаaБBбbÇĆĈĊČCçćĉċčcДDдdÐĎĐΔDjðďđδdjÈÉÊËĒĔĖĘĚΕΈẼẺẸỀẾỄỂỆЕЭEèéêëēĕėęěέεẽẻẹềếễểệеэeФFфfĜĞĠĢΓГҐGĝğġģγгґgĤĦHĥħhÌÍÎÏĨĪĬǏĮİΗΉΊΙΪỈỊИЫIìíîïĩīĭǐįıηήίιϊỉịиыїiĴJĵjĶΚКKķκкkĹĻĽĿŁΛЛLĺļľŀłλлlМMмmÑŃŅŇΝНNñńņňŉνнnÒÓÔÕŌŎǑŐƠØǾΟΌΩΏỎỌỒỐỖỔỘỜỚỠỞỢОOòóôõōŏǒőơøǿºοόωώỏọồốỗổộờớỡởợоoПPпpŔŖŘΡРRŕŗřρрrŚŜŞȘŠΣСSśŝşșšſσςсsȚŢŤŦτТTțţťŧтtÙÚÛŨŪŬŮŰŲƯǓǕǗǙǛŨỦỤỪỨỮỬỰУUùúûũūŭůűųưǔǖǘǚǜυύϋủụừứữửựуuÝŸŶΥΎΫỲỸỶỴЙYýÿŷỳỹỷỵйyВVвvŴWŵwŹŻŽΖЗZźżžζзzÆǼAEßssĲIJĳijŒOEƒf'ξksπpβvμmψpsЁYoёyoЄYeєyeЇYiЖZhжzhХKhхkhЦTsцtsЧChчchШShшshЩShchщshchЪъЬьЮYuюyuЯYaяya"
    /// After:  "aaeooeuueAAeUUeOOeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBbCCCCCCccccccDdDDjddjEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeFfGGGGGgggggHHhhIIIIIIIIIIIIIiiiiiiiiiiiiJJjjKKkkLLLLllllMmNNNNNnnnnnOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooPpRRRRrrrrSSSSSSssssssTTTTttttUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuYYYYYYYYyyyyyyyyVvWWwwZZZZzzzzAEssIJijOEf'kspvmpsYoyoYeyeYiZhzhKhkhTstsChchShshShchshchYuyuYaya"
    /// 
    /// Tests with invalid 'special hidden characters':
    /// Before: "\0\0\000\0000Bj��rk�\'\"\\\0\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\u0020���oacu\'\\\'te�"
    /// After:  "00000Bjrk'\"\\\n\r oacu'\\'te"
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private string Normalize(string StringToClean)
    {
        string normalizedString = StringToClean.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        StringBuilder Buffer = new StringBuilder(StringToClean.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < normalizedString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(normalizedString[i]) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                Buffer.Append(normalizedString[i]);
            }
        }

        string PreAsciiCompliant = Buffer.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        StringBuilder AsciiComplient = new StringBuilder(PreAsciiCompliant.Length);

        foreach (char character in PreAsciiCompliant)
        {
            //Reject all special characters except \n\r (Carriage-Return and Line-Feed). 
            //Get rid of special hidden character, like EOF, NUL, TAB and other '\0'
            if (((int)character >= 32 && (int)character < 127) || ((int)character == 10 || (int)character == 13)) 
            {
                AsciiComplient.Append(character);
            }
        }
        return AsciiComplient.ToString().Trim(); // Remove spaces at start and end of string if any
    }
```

Comment: This is from Java if I'm not wrong, why did you include it if it says "C"?