# How to remove accents from string in C?

Tags: c, non-ascii-characters

Is there is a more efficient way to remove accents from string without make an big array with the characters to replace?

For example:

```
removeaccents("áèfoo")
```

Output:

```
aefoo
```

In the ASCII table there no accents, I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can always use an if ladder instead of a translation table.

Comment: Any idea what encoding the strings would be using?

Comment: possible help question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144761/how-to-remove-accents-and-tilde-in-a-c-stdstring

Comment: @chikuba: It's not a duplicate - that question is about C++, while this is about C.

Comment: `"áèfoo"` is not a valid string literal.  what dfo you really want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`unac()`](http://www.makelinux.net/man/3/U/unac). From the man page:

> `unac`  is  a  C  library that removes accents from characters, regardless of the character set (ISO-8859-15, ISO-CELTIC, KOI8-RU...) as long as `iconv(3)` is able to convert it
>          into UTF-16 (Unicode).

I couldn't find the download page (I think it's meant to be [here](http://www.senga.org/download/unac/), but the link is currently 404ing). If you're on ubuntu, you can get it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libunac1-dev
```

Assuming you're using gcc, once it's installed you'll need to add `-lunac` to your compiler options (to tell the compiler to link with the unac library).

Comment: Thanks very much. :) I downloaded and installed, but when I try link and compile I get the following error:  `/tmp/ccAKGVl9.o: In function `main':
ILD.c:(.text+0x651): undefined reference to `unac_string'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
` my code: 

`#include <unac.h>
// ... 
 char* out = 0;
     size_t out_length = 0;
     
       if(unac_string("ISO-8859-1", "été", strlen("été"), &out, &out_length)) {
          printf("unac_string");
       } else {
          printf("%.*s0", out_length, out);
          free(out);
       }`

Comment: I solved using `-lunac` option on `gcc` and changed `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8` encoding and works fine now. Thanks you very much :)