# PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string

Tags: php, utf-8, diacritics, strtr

What I want to do is to remove all accents and umlauts from a string, turning "lärm" into "larm" or "andré" into "andre". What I tried to do was to utf8_decode the string and then use strtr on it, but since my source file is saved as UTF-8 file, I can't enter the ISO-8859-15 characters for all umlauts - the editor inserts the UTF-8 characters.

Obviously a solution for this would be to have an include that's an ISO-8859-15 file, but there must be a better way than to have another required include?

```
echo strtr(utf8_decode($input), 
           'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ',
           'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
```

**UPDATE:** Maybe I was a bit inaccurate with what I try to do: I do not actually want to remove the umlauts, but to replace them with their closest "one character ASCII" equivalent.

Comment: Keep in mind that the string you produce will not necessarily have the same meaning as the original string, as discussed in this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140422/how-do-i-translate-8bit-characters-into-7bit-characters-ie-220-to-u). It's a serviceable approach for cleaning file names, but probably not something you'd want to do if you are planning to display your new string as text.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However the resulting string will be used as a simplified version fallback for search if "binary search" fails. Even more simplifications will be applied after this one - to allow illiterates to still find what they are looking for :)

Comment: There actually is a valid reason to do it for displayed characters. Generation of HTML 4.1 compliant id attributes for navigation menus. For example, if I have <h3>Für Elise</h3> and I want to generate an id anchor above it, <a id="FurElise" /> is the best I can do and still be compliant with html 4.1 which may be necessary for some older browsers.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT",$input);
```

Extended [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#83238)

Comment: I had to add "setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');" (sadly no locals for Germany seem to be available on my machine :( ), but then it works. Great! :)

Comment: Why does this solution return `"o` for `ö` on my machine and on the examples in the [php reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#105507) it returns `oe`?

Comment: This does not work for Cyrillic characters. They are converted to ? question marks instead.

Comment: This bombs with a value of false and gives me a notice that illegal characters were encountered...

Comment: To spikey's comment: if you set your locale to de_*.UTF8 (de_DE.UTF8, de_CH.UTF8, etc.), then umlauts will be converted to *e (ü->ue). 

Set it to en_US..UTF8 to get the desired effect.

Comment: I have the same problem as spikey, setlocale stuff doesn't help also.

Comment: setlocale() depends on your operating system, is not thread-safe and wreaks havoc if you do it wrong (such as treating commas as periods in conversions). Either be careful (using LC_CTYPE instead of LC_ALL in this case) or stay away from it unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Use `"ascii//translit//ignore"` to prevent "illegal characters encountered" error.

Comment: If `iconv()` with `ASCII//TRANSLIT` doesn't work for you with German umlauts (ä/ö/ü => ae/oe/ue, despite setting `setlocale()` to a German utf8 locale, [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412085/how-to-make-textslug-convert-german-umlauts-properly#answer-50415750) was the solution for me, using [`transliterator_transliterate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) with `de-ASCII` supplied via the transliterator build string.

Answer (score 33):

A little trick that doesn't require setting locales or having huge translation tables:

```
function Unaccent($string)
{
    if (strpos($string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '&') !== false)
    {
        $string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $string;
}
```

The only requirement for it to work properly is to save your files in UTF-8 (as you should already).

Comment: Works great for hungarian

Answer (score 9):

you can also try this

```
$string = "Fóø Bår";
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
echo $normalized = $transliterator->transliterate($string);
```

but you need to have http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php available

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found an obvious solution myself, but it's not the best concerning performance...

```
echo strtr(utf8_decode($input), 
           utf8_decode('ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
           'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
```

Comment: It's not the best in terms of performance and it also produces incorrect result. Letters like Œ, Æ, etc. should decompose to two letters, not to one.

Comment: You have missed `žščřďťňů`, and that's just the ones I see on my keyboard. Whitelisting known characters is not the best solution.

Comment: @this.lau_ As mentioned in the question: I'm looking for the closest "one character ASCII", so no - two letter decomposition would not be correct for my use case. One letter is correct for what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress, you can use the built-in function `remove_accents( $string )`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents

However I noticed a bug : it doesn’t work on a string with a single character.

Comment: Despite not actually being an exact answer, I appreciate this answer as I'm using WordPress. So thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Arabic and Persian users i recommend this way to remove diacritics:

```
    $diacritics = array('َ','ِ','ً','ٌ','ٍ','ّ','ْ','ـ');
    $search_txt = str_replace($diacritics, '', $diacritics);
```

For typing diacritics in Arabic keyboards u can use this Asci(those codes are Asci not Unicode) codes in windows editors
typing diacritics directly or holding Alt + (type the code of diacritic character)
This is the codes

ـَ(0243)   ـِ(0246)    ـُ(0245)    ـً(0240)    ـٍ(0242)    ـٌ(0241)    ـْ(0250)    ـّ(0248)    ـ
ـ(0220)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this one gives the most consistent results in French and German.
with the meta tag set to `utf-8`, I have place it in a function to return a line from a array of words and it works perfect.

```
htmlentities (  $line, ENT_SUBSTITUTE   , 'utf-8' )
```

Comment: This will return HTML entities. eg München will become M&uuml;nchen. But the requested result should be Muenchen.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this:

1. Obtain the Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition of the text. See https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/ for Unicode Normalization Forms.
2. Remove nonspacing marks.
3. Obtain the Normalization Form Canonical Composition of the remaining text.

https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/

> For example, to remove accents from characters, use the following transform:

`NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC.`

I am a bit unsure why they have given this example as such when the page also notes

> each transform rule consists of two colons followed by a transform name.

So we will add those. You need the `intl` extension which wraps the `ICU` library.

```php
$t = \Transliterator::createFromRules(':: NFD; ::[:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;');
```

Example

```php
print $t->transliterate('أ');
```

This transforms U+0623 (Arabic Letter Alef with Hamza Above) to U+0627 (Arabic Letter Alef) ie it works with non-latin letters and their accents as well.

You can replace `[:Nonspacing Mark:]` with `[:Mn:]`.