# How to get rid of the non-english letters on the string?

Tags: php, special-characters, turkish

I want to get rid of the turkish characters with the english ones in the string and thats the function I wrote. However, in the server, its not recognized the letters. Any suggestions?

```
function strtolower_tr($string)
    {
        $low=array("Ü" => "U","ü" => "u", "Ö" => "O","ö" => "o", "Ğ" => "G","ğ" => "g", "Ş" => "S","ş" => "s", "Ç" => "C","ç" => "c", "İ" => "I","i" => "i", "I" => "i","I" => "I");
        return strtolower(strtr($string,$low));
    }
```

-------IN THE SERVER-------

```
$low=array("?~\" => "u?", "?~V" => "o?", "?~^" => "g", "?~^" => "s", "?~G" => "c", "İ" => "i", "I" => i");
```

### EDITED:

I found this: However, its not working for letter 'ı' and 'I'
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function clearUTF($s)
{
         $r = '';
    $s1 = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $s);
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s1); $i++) {
        $ch1 = $s1[$i];
        $ch2 = @mb_substr($s, $j++, 1, 'UTF-8');
        if (strstr('`^~\'"', $ch1) !== false) {
            if ($ch1 <> $ch2) {
                --$j;
                continue;
            }
        }
        $r .= ($ch1=='?') ? $ch2 : $ch1;
    }
    return $r;
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)

Comment: I found this but there is a problem its not working for character 'ı 'setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function clearUTF($s)
{
         $r = '';
    $s1 = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $s);
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s1); $i++) {
        $ch1 = $s1[$i];
        $ch2 = @mb_substr($s, $j++, 1, 'UTF-8');
        if (strstr('`^~\'"', $ch1) !== false) {
            if ($ch1 <> $ch2) {
                --$j;
                continue;
            }
        }
        $r .= ($ch1=='?') ? $ch2 : $ch1;
    }
    return $r;
}

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Is you file in utf encoding? You should use utf encoding for your source files, this will solve your problem.

Comment: You could use one of many editors like CodeLobster, Notepad++, Zend IDE, etc where you can strictly set preferable encoding.