# Replace worldwide diacritics characters

Tags: php, diacritics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)

I want to replace diacritics characters with his non-diacritics brother.
example: from "guľôčka" I wanna get "gulocka"

Is here some native function to do it?

I was looking for list of all worldwide diacritics characters for replace with str_replace. I can't find it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `iconv`, [available in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php), and requesting an encoding conversion with **transliteration**. (This actually works for many different scripts!) If you only want basic European characters, make the target Latin-1, or even ASCII.

From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code will return "gulôcka" - it doesn't replace ô. As target I tried Latin-1, ASCII and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Can you print the result in raw hex? Is the accent a separate byte? If so, you can run a regex over the result and strip non-alphanumerics.

Comment: `$text = 'guľôčka';
$iso = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text);

var_dump(strlen($iso)); //int(7)´ So I think, it's  in 1 byte. I don't want to strip, I need replace.

Comment: @Peter: Don't target ISO-8859-1, but a genuine 7-bit ASCII encoding instead!

Comment: @Peter: There you go - now just run a regex over this to sieve out the non-alphabetical characters!