# Change special characters in array Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

Some string that I am getting is UTF-8 encoded, and contains some special characters like
 Å¡, Ä‘, Ä etc. I am using `StringReplace()` to convert it to some normal text, but I can only convert one type of character. Because PHP also has a function to replace strings as seen here: [how to replace special characters with the ones they're based on in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php), but it supports arrays:

```
<?php
  $vOriginalString = "¿Dónde está el niño que vive aquí? En el témpano o en el iglú. ÁFRICA, MÉXICO, ÍNDICE, CANCIÓN y NÚMERO.";

  $vSomeSpecialChars = array("á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú", "Á", "É", "Í", "Ó", "Ú", "ñ", "Ñ");
  $vReplacementChars = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "n", "N");

  $vReplacedString = str_replace($vSomeSpecialChars, $vReplacementChars, $vOriginalString);

  echo $vReplacedString; // outputs '¿Donde esta el nino que vive aqui? En el tempano o en el iglu. AFRICA, MEXICO, INDICE, CANCION y NUMERO.'
?>
```

How can I do this in Delphi? `StringReplace` doesn't support arrays.

Comment: The string is UTF-8 encoded **and** contains "special characters"? What's a "special character"? Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552477/replace-worldwide-diacritics-characters/6552564#6552564) too -- if you have access to `iconv`.

Comment: If you want this for comparison, then use [CompareString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317759(v=vs.85).aspx) with at least `NORM_IGNORENONSPACE` in `dwCmpFlags`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function str_replace(const oldChars, newChars: array of Char; const str: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Length(oldChars)=Length(newChars));
  Result := str;
  for i := 0 to high(oldChars) do
    Result := StringReplace(Result, oldChars[i], newChars[i], [rfReplaceAll])
end;
```

If you are concerned about all the needless heap allocations caused by `StringReplace` then you could write it this way:

```
function str_replace(const oldChars, newChars: array of Char; const str: string): string;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Length(oldChars)=Length(newChars));
  Result := str;
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
    for j := 0 to high(oldChars) do
      if Result[i]=oldChars[j] then
      begin
        Result[i] := newChars[j];
        break;
      end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
newStr := str_replace(
  ['á','é','í'],
  ['a','e','i'], 
  oldStr
);
```

Comment: @Thalvik To save you some work, [here's](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?p=295849#post295849) a complete array (among others I'm sure).

Answer (score 6):

Getting rid of your accents is called [Normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html).

Since you are using Unicode, you are not only wanting to normalize the short list of accented characters in your question. In fact you are looking for Unicode [Normalization Form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) D (NFD) or KD (NFKD), which you can do in Windows and of course in Delphi.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891196/convert-hi-ansi-chars-to-ascii-equivalent-e-e-in-delphi2007/1892432#1892432) should get you going on the theoretical side.

[This Delphi code](http://www.delphitop.com/html/danyuan/1472.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891196/convert-hi-ansi-chars-to-ascii-equivalent-e-e-in-delphi2007) should get you going implementing.

Comment: This sounds like the right approach. I just naively answered the question as asked.

Comment: Sorry, "getting rid of accents" is **not** normalization -- it's just getting rid of accents! Normalization doesn't change the semantics of the character, it just chooses between "base plus diacritic" and "legacy Latin-1" form (and some other forms if appropriate) in a consistent fashion so that two normalized strings compare equal if they're semantically equal. The OP's goal appears to be *transliteration* to ASCII-only characters.

Comment: @Kerrek: I inferred Normalization because the OP links to the PHP solution mentioning Normalization.

Comment: @Jeroen: Even the linked accepted SO answer is wrong, as pointed out in its comments; the [PHP normalize function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) does exactly what the Unicode standard says and what I said. It does *not* transliterate ä to a!

Comment: @Jeroen: Well, I would prefer `iconv`ing to ASCII//TRANSLIT and then regexing `\w` out, I think that's a bit simpler and more foolproof...

Comment: @Kerrek: there is no iconv in Delphi.

Comment: @Jeroen: Shame. No way to pull in a C library? Oh well, in that case you'll have to roll your own transliterator, indeed.

Comment: @Kerrek: importing LIB files in Delphi is a pain; OBJ files can be done, but is hard. The easiest is to import DLLs. Same BTW is in .NET: importing OBJ/LIB there is virtually impossible too.