# PHP Convert umlauts from e.g. "ue" to "ü"

Tags: php, diacritics

Is there a way to convert umlauts from the representations `ae, Ae, oe, Oe, ue, Ue` and `ss`, back to the original umlauts? Important is that the spelling is observed like "teuer"! For example, the term "`teuer`" must **not be changed** in "`teür`". Thanks!

Comment: No, I rather don't think so. You would need a dictionary with all  exceptions.

Comment: You would need a dictionary of all the acceptable words to convert, and be sure not to convert partials (a la 'clbuttic').

Comment: "back to the original umlauts" - are you converting them in the first place?  Sounds like you could just retain the information instead.

Comment: My German is a bit rusty, but from memory there are well defined rules for most cases ([vowel][vowel]e doesn't change, [consonent][vowel]e does, [start of word][vowel]e does, etc), so something like (in regex) `/^[^aeiou]?[aeiou]e/` would match most cases. You'd still need a dictionary with specific exceptions, but the general case would pick up most.

Answer (score 3):

```
iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT",$input);
```

Extended [`example`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#83238)

OR

```
echo strtr(utf8_decode($input), 
           utf8_decode('ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
           'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string) question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert each permutation of occurences of "ue", "oe" and so on.
By each permutation I mean if there are 3 occurences first replace only the first, then only the second, then only the third, then first and second and so on.

Next, check if the results are contained in a standard spellchecking dictionary. By this you do not have to create your own dictionary for exceptions.

A wordlist can be found for example on ftp://ftp.ox.ac.uk/pub/wordlists/german/words.german.Z

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be pretty tricky to get right. There certainly isn't any built-in function to do it.

Most of the examples I've seen for this kind of thing work in the opposite direction (ie taking a string with accented characters and replacing them with their ASCII equivalents). Where I have seen it done, it's always been a case of providing a map of characters and their equivalents, and scanning the string doing replacements.

The PHP manual page for the [`strtr()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) has some good examples on the kind of thing you'd need to do, but your requirements to avoid specific exceptions is going to complicate the whole process enormously.