# PHP: Convert specific-Bosnian characters to non-bosnian (utf8 standard chars)

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, special-characters, string-conversion

In Bosnia we have following characters only used in latin-form in Bosnia and Croatia, so I'd need to convert these letters as following:

```
FROM | TO
  ć  | c
  č  | c
  ž  | z
  š  | s
  đ  | dj
```

If this is possible with some special form of RegEx, or utf8_encode/decode, that informatiion and an appopriate example will be quite welcome! Thanks all.

PS - Want to achive this in PHP!

Comment: For the `đ` to `dj` conversion, you would need a regex or string replace. Everything else is already covered by [the many iconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string) answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this with iconv.

```
$result = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

That will work assuming your input `$text` is in utf-8. If it's in latin-1 then use

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

Of cause your PHP must have `iconv` extension, most often `iconv` is enabled in `php.ini` file, but not always.

Comment: What this does is translate non-ASCII char to the most similar replacement char in ASCII. For this to work you should also set your locale before calling this function: setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$search = array("ć", "č", "ž", "š", "đ");
$replacement = array("c", "c", "z", "s", "dj");
$new_string = str_replace($search, $replacement, $string);
```

Also, check out [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)