# italic quotes problematic in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem I've been working on for the last 3 hours. When I insert in the field something like this:

`„It is a beautiful day“ after update I get this`

`„It is a beautiful dayâ`

I am not sure why this started to happen now, before it was working normally. Is this the problem with mysql? Because I type normally this sign, like italic quotes up and than I update it and get this strange `â` on the end.

Does anyone knows something more about it? I was trying almost everything. My encoding of database is set to utf8-general-ci, of page utf-8. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Getting `â` means a charset problem - your ENTIRE pipeline has to keep the SAME charset (e.g. utf-8) throughout, or have appropriate charset translation logic at the "borders". If you stuff a utf-8 string through a (say) iso-8859 connection or table, then you're going to get corrupted strings like this. That means your client code, your client->database connection, your tables, your fields, ALL have to be set up correctly.

Comment: so what do you propose? because the problem is that I have utf-8-general-ci in the database and on page I cannot change it since framework makes it automatically,generates utf-8

Comment: make everything utf-8. your client-side data, your db connection, etc...

Comment: There are a few different places where you might be able to set this. The database connection code might have an option to us UTF-8, like in the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249695/1451957 ; I wrote about a few other places where you can "opt in" to UTF-8 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603421/how-to-compare-and-output-latin-characters/12604900#12604900 ; These might not all be relevant to you (it sounds like you're using a framework, which should be taking care of some of these for you), but it might be a good place to start.