# Zend has some kind of transliteration?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm like 1 day new to Zend and i ran into my first problem.
It seems i can't find anything in google or documentation about string transliteration.

For example Kohana has [UTF8::transliterate_to_ascii](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/UTF8#transliterate_to_ascii)

I need to turn all sort of characters (ę, ų ...) to english looking ones.

How you do that in Zend?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: Use iconv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string instead

Comment: @akond for iconv to work i need to change locale with setlocale(), how that possibly would impact on other code in zend?

Comment: You could save current locale, apply a new one, and after the iconv () is done, resort to the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string) provided by akond i resolved my issue:

First get current locale and store it:
`$orginial_locale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0);`

After set locale to one you desire:
`setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');`

Then apply [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to string:
`iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);`

And finaly restore back to original locale:
`setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $orginial_locale);`

You should adjust setlocale category based on your needs see [setlocale](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) documentation for information on categories.

Comment: Unknows characters are converted to question marks.