# Why won't my extension render umlauts?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I am working on an extension to display downloads on a website. You can view the full, current source over [on GitHub](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/downloads).

Given this piece of code in my [controller](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/downloads/blob/master/Classes/Controller/DownloadController.php):

```
  $linkName = Tx_Downloads_Utility_Filename::construct( $download );
  $download->setLinkText( $linkName );
```

This is where I want to set the label for a download. Sadly, when it is later rendered, the result will be blank if `$linkName` contained an umlaut (umlauts were just my test subject, the actual scope is unknown).

For debugging purposes, I have extended that section to look like this:

```
  $linkName = Tx_Downloads_Utility_Filename::construct( $download );
  $download->setLinkText( $linkName );
  $this->flashMessages->add( "'" . strlen( $linkName ) . "'" );
  $this->flashMessages->add( urlencode( $linkName ) );
  $this->flashMessages->add( $linkName );
```

The resulting output of that is:
[image]
Please note that no third flash message is rendered.

---

But it's not like no umlauts would be rendered. For example, this is the record I am debugging with:

[image]

The link field (between the image icon and the 31.06KB) is blank but should say `Text_File_Sömething.jpg`. The string `Sömething` is rendered perfectly fine in another place of the template.

Is the problem with my [Fluid template](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/downloads/blob/master/Resources/Private/Partials/List/Download.html)?

Comment: Thats rather strange. Could you try to debug this?

Comment: @pgampe: Sadly, not with an actual debugger (I have no working setup). And debug()-debugging is quite hard if you have no clue where to start :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that was not really clear. Next try:
you call `Tx_Downloads_Utility_Filename::construct($linkName)` which (by default) calls `Tx_Downloads_Utility_Filename::clean($linkName)` which again removes all the special characters by replacing anything that doesn't match the regex pattern `/([[:alnum:]_\.-]*)/` by underscores.
There seems to be a problem with encoding (maybe your db is not set to UTF-8 encoding) so **Text_File_Sömething** is actually turned into **Text_File_SÃ¶mething** and the clean() method turns that into an invalid string. try using `utf8_encode()` on the `$filename` first.

Comment: Awesome! I was looking in the completely wrong spot. I used [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string) to convert the filenames down now :) Thanks