# PHP Replace umlaut characters to parse XML; several methods not working

Tags: php, xml, replace, special-characters

I have the following problem: I have a php page which parses an XML file. The php gets an ID, then queries the database to get the information from that ID and outputs this info as XML. As it happens, there are special characters in the DB, specifically [é, è, ö, ä, ü.. etc ]. The file is saved as UTF-8 (I tried saving as UTF-16, but the output looked horrible).
The php file looks like this:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes" ?>';
    include ('config.php');
    echo '<response>';
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    // configure server request
    $db_q1 = "SELECT * from table WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
    $db_r1 = mysql_query($db_q1);
    while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_r1)) {
        $string = $rec["name"];
        ...
    }
    echo '<name>' . $string . '</name>';

    echo '<response>';
    ?>
```

This file works well with any db-entry that has no special characters, but when it does, I get the following error: Encoding error. This happens precisely at the point of the special character, i.e., the xml is parsed up to there. After researching the error, I figured it must be due to the special characters (also because the xml was parsed till there and worked for other entries).

I have tried the following, based on research here and elsewhere and after reading the php manual of certain techniques:

- $string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
  --> works, but cuts off string from special character ("Brötchen" --> "Br").
- $string = str_replace(search, replace, $string); 
  --> Has simply no effect. I get the same error.
- Using a function which will return an altered string, e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string), which also did not have any effect.
- htmlentities($string) --> I get the following error: "Entity 'uuml' not defined".
- htmlspecialchars() returns the original error.
- urlencode() is not useful, because it treats the string as url and adds "+".
- the following function (unfortunately, I don't remember where I got it, otherwise I would credit the person who wrote it, as it seems to be useful):

  ```
  function remove_accents($str)
  { 
     $from = array(
       "á", "à", "â", "ã", "ä", "é", "è", "ê", "ë", "í", "ì", "î", "ï", 
       "ó", "ò", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ç", "Á", "À", "Â", 
       "Ã", "Ä", "É", "È", "Ê", "Ë", "Í", "Ì", "Î", "Ï", "Ó", "Ò", "Ô", 
       "Õ", "Ö", "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü", "Ç"
     ); 
     $to = array(
       "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "e", "e", "e", "e", "i", "i", "i", "i", 
       "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "u", "u", "u", "u", "c", "A", "A", "A", 
       "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "E", "I", "I", "I", "I", "O", "O", "O", 
       "O", "O", "U", "U", "U", "U", "C"
     );
  return str_replace($from, $to, $str); 
  }

  $string = remove_accents($string);
  ```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and why so many different methods fail at accomplishing this task. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function from Wordpress core which removes accents from letters, it should work:

```
function remove_accents($string) {
    if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
        return $string;

    if (seems_utf8($string)) {
        $chars = array(
        // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
        chr(194).chr(170) => 'a', chr(194).chr(186) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(134) => 'AE',chr(195).chr(135) => 'C',
        chr(195).chr(136) => 'E', chr(195).chr(137) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(138) => 'E', chr(195).chr(139) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(140) => 'I', chr(195).chr(141) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(142) => 'I', chr(195).chr(143) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(144) => 'D', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
        chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
        chr(195).chr(158) => 'TH',chr(195).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(195).chr(160) => 'a', chr(195).chr(161) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(162) => 'a', chr(195).chr(163) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(164) => 'a', chr(195).chr(165) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(166) => 'ae',chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
        chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(176) => 'd', chr(195).chr(177) => 'n',
        chr(195).chr(178) => 'o', chr(195).chr(179) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(180) => 'o', chr(195).chr(181) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(184) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(185) => 'u', chr(195).chr(186) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(187) => 'u', chr(195).chr(188) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(189) => 'y', chr(195).chr(190) => 'th',
        chr(195).chr(191) => 'y', chr(195).chr(152) => 'O',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
        chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
        chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
        chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
        chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
        chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
        chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
        chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-B
        chr(200).chr(152) => 'S', chr(200).chr(153) => 's',
        chr(200).chr(154) => 'T', chr(200).chr(155) => 't',
        // Euro Sign
        chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E',
        // GBP (Pound) Sign
        chr(194).chr(163) => '',
        // Vowels with diacritic (Vietnamese)
        // unmarked
        chr(198).chr(160) => 'O', chr(198).chr(161) => 'o',
        chr(198).chr(175) => 'U', chr(198).chr(176) => 'u',
        // grave accent
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(166) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(167) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(176) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(177) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(128) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(129) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(146) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(147) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(156) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(157) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(170) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(178) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(179) => 'y',
        // hook
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(162) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(163) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(168) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(169) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(178) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(179) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(186) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(187) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(130) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(131) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(136) => 'I', chr(225).chr(187).chr(137) => 'i',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(142) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(148) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(149) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(158) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(159) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(166) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(167) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(172) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(183) => 'y',
        // tilde
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(170) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(171) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(180) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(181) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(188) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(189) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(132) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(133) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(150) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(151) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(160) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(161) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(174) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(185) => 'y',
        // acute accent
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(164) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(165) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(174) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(175) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(190) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(191) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(144) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(154) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(155) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(168) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(169) => 'u',
        // dot below
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(160) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(161) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(172) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(173) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(182) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(183) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(184) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(185) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(134) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(135) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(138) => 'I', chr(225).chr(187).chr(139) => 'i',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(140) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(152) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(153) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(162) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(163) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(164) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(165) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(176) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(180) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(181) => 'y',
        );

        $string = strtr($string, $chars);
    } else {
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
        $chars['in'] = chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
            .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
            .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
            .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
            .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
            .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
            .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
            .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
            .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
            .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255);

        $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

        $string = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
        $double_chars['in'] = array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254));
        $double_chars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
        $string = str_replace($double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Any idea what was wrong with the other attempts? (Also, in order to use it you need to include the function seems_utf9(), which is called in the remove_accents() function. You can  get it from [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0) .

Comment: Probably your issue was specifying characters directly, and not by hex /decimal codes, like wordpress function does. Because when you specify characters directly, your source code file encoding will matter too.

Comment: @user1889382: don't you mean seems_utf8? :-)

Answer (score 1):

For others who experience similar problems; I also had problems with string replace on variables that came in via POST.

This worked for me:

```
$string = str_replace(
array('ä','á','à','â','ë','é','è','ê','ï','í','ì','î','ö','ó','ò','ô','ü','ú','ù','û'),
array('a','a','a','a','e','e','e','e','i','i','i','i','o','o','o','o','u','u','u','u'),
utf8_encode($string)));
```

utf8_encode() did the trick!

I needed only lower case, if you need upper case you will have to add all the uppercase variants for these special characters.