# Loop through XML-Object in php

Tags: php, xml, loops

i'm trying to loop through an xml object like this …

```
$xml_url = "http://somdomain.com/frieventexport.php";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url );

$xml = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML( $xml );

var_dump($document);
//echo $document->childNodes[1];
```

With `var_dump` I get this.

`object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> NULL ["lastChild"]=> NULL ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(0) "" }`

does anybody know how to extract information out of this and use the single xml-items?

this would be in the xml:

```
<event>
<titel>Eventtitle</titel>
<datum>07.03.2015</datum>
<von>18:30</von>
<bis>23:00</bis>
<ort>Something</ort>
<referent>BezRKdo</referent>
<veranstalter>Who does it.</veranstalter>
</event>
```

I don't know how to loop through this dump and extract the information.
Kind Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$xml_url = "http://localhost/site.xml";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url );

$xml = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML( $xml );

$events = $document->getElementsByTagName("event");

foreach( $events as $event ){
    $titels = $event->getElementsByTagName( "titel" );
    $titel= $titels->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $datums = $event->getElementsByTagName( "datum" );
    $datum = $datums->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $titel;

}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the XML comes with this domain above and this should be dynamic. So the `$xml` variable you point out, does not exist in this way. See my var_dump() output. If I `echo $titel` within the foreach loop i get no output.

Comment: Also if I just put `$events = $document->getElementsByTagName("event");
 var_dump($events);` outside the loop I get this `object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: I gave the example of the XML variable. You must change the xml you fetching from the remote site. if you give the URL is not special, i can help you

Comment: doesnt work because xml give a error "Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xDC 0x62 0x75 0x6E in Entity, line: 3". i fixed, put your code $xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml); and i'm updated my answer above

Comment: thank you, please just remove the acutal url from your answer, I'll give it a try.

Comment: thank you, seems to work except for the "Umlauts" in the Titel, those are neglected. It says "bung" in the output instead of "Übung" in the actual xml.

Comment: Thank you, only last problem are the "Umlauts".

Comment: does not give me the error, you can take screenshots? and look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500313/php-replace-umlaut-characters-to-parse-xml-several-methods-not-working

Comment: hey @MustafaToker no, does not work for me … https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3a0znt8boxpx0c/xml-test.php?dl=0 I still get no Umlauts, what could cause this? Any ideas?

Comment: use $xml = utf8_encode($xml); instead of  $xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);

Answer (score 0):

You have only a single record in the XML, each data element is unique. You can use XPath to fetch the data as strings.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/event/titel)'), "\n";
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/event/datum)'), ' ';
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/event/von)'), '-';
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/event/bis)');
```

Output:

```
Übung Einhausung Amras
07.03.2015 18:30-23:00
```

If your XML would return multiple events you would need to loop the event elements and use the node as context:

XML structure for multiple elements:

```
<events>
  <event>
    <titel>Übung Einhausung Amras</titel>
    ...
  </event>
  <event>
    <titel>Other event</titel>
    ...
  </event>
  ...
</events>
```

PHP iterating over multiple records in XML:

```
foreach($xpath->evaluate('/events/event' as $event) {
  echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/event/titel)', $event), "\n";
  // ...
}
```

### Encoding

The XML declaration in the response is missing the encoding. It is `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, but it should be something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`.

DOMDocument uses UTF-8 by default. You can convert the string or make sure that the XML defines the encoding.

```
$xml = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);
```

Because of the used charset, utf8_encode() should work, too:

```
$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
```