# Parsing XML using curl returning null

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to parse an RSS feed and I am getting what appears to be an empty DOM Document object. My current code is:

```
$xml_url = "https://thehockeywriters.com/category/san-jose-sharks/feed/";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url );

    $xml = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );

    //$xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);
    //$xml = utf8_encode($xml);
    $document = new DOMDocument;
    $document->loadXML( $xml ); 
    if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
      echo "allow url fopen? Yes";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($document);

    $items = $document->getElementsByTagName("item");

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title');
        echo $title;
    }

    $url = 'https://thehockeywriters.com/category/san-jose-sharks/feed/';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $title = $item->title;
        echo $title;
    }
    print_r($xml);
    echo "<br />";
    var_dump($xml);
    echo "<br />hello?";
```

This code is two separate attempts at parsing the same url based on answers and suggestions given in the following examples found on stack overflow:
[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538787/php-read-a-php-url-as-xml-and-parse-it)
[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676436/loop-through-xml-object-in-php)

Things I have tried or looked up:
1. Checked to make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is allowed
2. Made sure that there is UTF encoding 
3. Validated the XML 
4. Code examples provided on previously linked Stack Overflow posts

Here is my current output with the `var_dumps` and `echo's`

```
allow url fopen? Yes
object(DOMDocument)#2 (34) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" 
["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL 
["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) 
["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" 
["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL 
["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) 
["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) 
["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL 
["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> NULL ["lastChild"]=> NULL 
["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL 
["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(0) "" } 
bool(false) 
hello?
```

Comment: Neither of the answers you've looked at previously are using SSL. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372710/php-curl-https I think the issue is the certificate.

Comment: Hmm, I tried the quickfix `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` just to see if it would work and it did not. Plus, I guess that is a security issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I had with your code was that not defining a user-agent would give me error 403 to access the feed.

In the future, you could use `curl_getinfo` to extract the status code of the request to ensure it didn't failed and further match it against code 200, which means OK.

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Aside from that a few mistakes within your loops.

With SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$url = "https://thehockeywriters.com/category/san-jose-sharks/feed/";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

if ($httpcode !== 200)
{
    echo "Failed to retrieve feed... Error code: $httpcode";
    die();
}

$feed = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
// list all titles...
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo $item->title, "<br>\n";
}
```

With DOMDocument:

```
<?php
$url = "https://thehockeywriters.com/category/san-jose-sharks/feed/";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

if ($httpcode !== 200)
{
    echo "Failed to retrieve feed... Error code: $httpcode";
    die();
}

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);
// list all titles...
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName("item") as $item)
{
    foreach ($item->getElementsByTagName("title") as $title)
    {
        echo $title->nodeValue, "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

If you just want to print the title/description of all items:

```
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item)
{
    echo $item->title;
    echo $item->description;
    // uncomment the below line to print only the first entry.
    // break;
}
```

If you want just the first entry, without using a foreach:

```
echo $feed->channel->item[0]->title;
echo $feed->channel->item[0]->description;
```

Saving title and description to an array for later using it:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item)
{
    $result[] = 
    [
        'title' => (string)$item->title,
        'description' => (string)$item->description
    ];
    // could make a key => value alternatively from the above with 
    // title as key like this: 
    // $result[(string)$item->title] = (string)$item->description;
}
```

Foreach with MySQLi/PDO prepared statement:

```
foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item)
{
    // MySQLi
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $item->title, $item->description);
    $stmt->execute();
    // PDO
    //$stmt->bindParam(':title', $item->title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':description', $item->description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: As soon as I added that useragent line, I was able to get it to work. Thank you. Fixed the loop too, like you mentioned.

Comment: @KurtLeadley you could further use `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` to verify the code is 200 to ensure you got the data as well, see updated code.

Comment: Ahh, very nice. I need to do more research on the curl options.

Answer (score 1):

I selected Prix's answer for pointing out the user agent definition, but I came up with another way of doing the loop that avoids nested loops and makes it easier to access other nodes. Here is what I am using (DOM Document solution):

```
$xml_url = "https://thehockeywriters.com/category/san-jose-sharks/feed/";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");

$xml = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML( $xml ); 

$items = $document->getElementsByTagName("item");       
foreach ($items as $item) {     
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $title;
    $desc = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $desc;
}
```

Comment: I still prefer SimpleXML, it feels to me more straight forward to use, I've added 3 other examples to show you that.

Comment: I see! This is great. I have options next time. I happened to have a working version of code similar to what I just posted myself, so I went with that. I'm interested in trying the array one. Could the array solution reduce SQL insert query's? Right now I insert to my db per loop.

Comment: If you're using a framework like codeigniter you could use it for a bulk insert but it would be pretty much a loop behind the scenes. Just make sure you're using prepared statements to bind all that data within your foreach to avoid headaches later.

Comment: Added an example at the bottom of what it would look like using MySQLi bind_param with the foreach just in case ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've been yelled at enough to know better and always use prepared statements haha. Already have the March articles pulling from my websites db : ) http://sjsharktank.com/index.php