# Convert 2 similarly-looking German characters of different kinds to same ASCII string in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have these two strings:

```
$str1 = 'Ö';
$str2 = 'Ö';
$e1 = mb_detect_encoding($str1);
$e2 = mb_detect_encoding($str2);
var_dump($str1);
var_dump($str2);
echo 'e1: '.$e1.', e2: '.$e2;
```

the result is:

```
string(3) "Ö"
string(2) "Ö"
e1: UTF-8, e2: UTF-8
```

It seems that they are not only German characters but also each of them is different so converting them to ASCII this way

[PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)

doesn't produce equal results. Is there a way to convert both of these strings to one of these ASCII forms `BNOE` or `BNO`?

---

I know that maybe I could copy Ö from both and include in `strtr` search and replace array but I don't know how to reproduce all the charactes encoded the same way the first Ös are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first convert your input to utf-8 using `iconv` and then apply your conversion to ASCII. To detect the current encoding you can use `mb_detect_encoding`.

```
$aUTF8 = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($a, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true), 'UTF-8', $a);
$bUTF8 = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($b, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true), 'UTF-8', $b);

$aASCII = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $aUTF8);
$bASCII = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $bUTF8);
```

Please note that you might have to add additional encodings to the encoding list of `mb_detect_encoding`.

Answer (score 9):

These are two different forms to express the same letter in Unicode; one is the combination of an O with combining diereses, the other is the letter Ö. [Unicode allows either variant to express "Ö".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

To ***normalize*** that into your preferred variant, use [`Normalizer::normalize`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php):

```
$str = Normalizer::normalize('Ö', Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

Likely you want Form C, which will converge on "Ö" (the single letter form). If you prefer "O" + combining diereses, use Form D instead.

Comment: This. Thank you so much for this answer. I tested it on multiple systems and so far this is the best solution without and search/replace or converting from one encoding to another! This should the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Extending Andreas's answer. These characters are letter + combining diaeresis(U-0308). I was able to search and replace them to standard umlauts, then replace with whatever is needed. This is the fuction I've used to replace them:

```
function convertToUmlauts($str) {
    $srp_array = ['Ö' => 'Ö', 'Ä' => 'Ä', 'Ü' => 'Ü', '̈a' => 'ä', 'ö' => 'ö', 'ü' => 'ü'];
    return strtr($str, $srp_array);
}
```