# How to avoid combining diaeresis char in pdflib

Tags: php, pdflib

I have content entered by an user which will be inserted into a pdf created by PDFlib.

Some user now have entered some text which seems to have [combining diaeresis](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0308).

These are displayed in the pdf as `a` (with space after) instead of `ä`. When I convert this UTF-8 text in an editor to ANSI i got `a¨`. In the database and on the website this characters are displayed correctly as `ä`.

Do I miss some Configuration for the textflow option list? Or do I have to convert this string? How can I convert this string correctly?

My Code to display these is as followed:

```
$itemOptlist = "charref encoding=unicode fontname=Helvetica fontsize=12 leading=120% alignment=justify leftindent=20";
$tf = $p->add_textflow($tf, '...Arbeitsabläufe...' /* This Text comes from the database */, $itemOptlist);
```

Comment: Replacing those byte sequences with their counterparts is probably your best bet (not sure if PDFlib can handle that on it’s own; not all libs out there have “Unicode” fully implemented), https://stackoverflow.com/a/37024147/1427878 has an easy way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I have tried successfully the normalizer to get the diaeresis replaced.