# Special ä ö characters break UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

A user on my site inputted special characters into a text field: ä ö

These apparently are not the same ä ö characters I can input from my keyboard because when I paste them into Programmer's Notepad, they split into two: a¨ o¨

On my site's server side I have a PHP script that identifies illegal special characters in user input and highligts them in an html error message with `preg_replace`.

The character splitting happens there too so I get a normal letter a and o with a weird lone xCC character that breaks the UTF-8 string encoding and `json_encode` function fails as a result.

What would be the best way to handle these characters? Should I try to replace the special ä ö chars and replace them with the regular ones or can I somehow catch the broken UTF-8 chars and remove or replace them?

Comment: Sounds like its possible that your script isn't set to UTF8 *all the way through*, have a look at [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827) and [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?rq=1).

Comment: @Qirel I don't think there's any problem with encoding here; the behaviour of copy and pasting them suggests they're valid combining diacritics, the script just wasn't expecting those.

Comment: @deceze I'm not convinced [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021985/convert-2-similarly-looking-german-characters-of-different-kinds-to-same-ascii-s) is an appropriate duplicate. Both are about normalization, but that one wants ASCII, this one is happy to work with UTF-8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that these characters have broken the encoding, it's just that **Unicode is really complicated**.

Commonly used accented letters have their own *code points* in the Unicode standard, in this case:

- U+00E4 "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"
- U+00F6 "LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS"

However, to avoid encoding every possibility, particularly when multiple diacritics (accents) need to be placed on the same letter, Unicode includes "combining diacritics", such as:

- U+0308 "COMBINING DIAERESIS"

When placed after the code point for a normal letter, these code points *add a diacritic to it* when displaying.

As you've seen, this means there's two different ways to represent the same letter. To help with this, Unicode includes "normalization forms" [defined in an annex to the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/):

- Normalization Form D (NFD): Canonical Decomposition
- Normalization Form C (NFC): Canonical Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition
- Normalization Form KD (NFKD): Compatibility Decomposition
- Normalization Form KC (NFKC): Compatibility Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition

Ignoring the "Compatibility" forms for now, we have two options:

- Decomposition, which uses combining diacritics as often as possible
- Composition, which uses specific code points as often as possible

So one possibility is to convert your input into NFC, which in PHP can be achieved with [the `Normalizer` class in the `intl` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php).

However, **not all combinations can be normalised to a form with no separate diacritics**, so this doesn't solve all your problems. You'll also need to look at what characters exactly you want to allow, probably by [matching Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

You might also want to learn about "grapheme clusters" and use [the relevant PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php). A "grapheme cluster", or just "grapheme", is what most readers will think of as "a character" - e.g. a letter with all its diacritics, or a full ideogram.

Comment: The Normalizer class did indeed resolve the character issue. Thanks for the answer, it was very informative. I'll have to study the matter further and tune my solution.