# Setting nodeValue of text node in Javascript when string contains html entities

Tags: javascript, dom, html-entities, nodevalue

When I set a value of a text node with

```
node.nodeValue="string with &#xxxx; sort of characters"
```

ampersand gets escaped. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use Javascript escapes for the Unicode characters:

```
node.nodeValue="string with \uxxxx sort of characters"
```

Comment: Just FYI, this requires having a meta tag in your HTML document that sets the charset to `utf-8` otherwise &nbsp; will be decoded as junk.

Answer (score 5):

From http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips:

(converts both entity references and numeric entities)

```
const entityToCode = { __proto__: null,
apos:0x0027,quot:0x0022,amp:0x0026,lt:0x003C,gt:0x003E,nbsp:0x00A0,iexcl:0x00A1,cent:0x00A2,pound:0x00A3,
curren:0x00A4,yen:0x00A5,brvbar:0x00A6,sect:0x00A7,uml:0x00A8,copy:0x00A9,ordf:0x00AA,laquo:0x00AB,
not:0x00AC,shy:0x00AD,reg:0x00AE,macr:0x00AF,deg:0x00B0,plusmn:0x00B1,sup2:0x00B2,sup3:0x00B3,
acute:0x00B4,micro:0x00B5,para:0x00B6,middot:0x00B7,cedil:0x00B8,sup1:0x00B9,ordm:0x00BA,raquo:0x00BB,
frac14:0x00BC,frac12:0x00BD,frac34:0x00BE,iquest:0x00BF,Agrave:0x00C0,Aacute:0x00C1,Acirc:0x00C2,Atilde:0x00C3,
Auml:0x00C4,Aring:0x00C5,AElig:0x00C6,Ccedil:0x00C7,Egrave:0x00C8,Eacute:0x00C9,Ecirc:0x00CA,Euml:0x00CB,
Igrave:0x00CC,Iacute:0x00CD,Icirc:0x00CE,Iuml:0x00CF,ETH:0x00D0,Ntilde:0x00D1,Ograve:0x00D2,Oacute:0x00D3,
Ocirc:0x00D4,Otilde:0x00D5,Ouml:0x00D6,times:0x00D7,Oslash:0x00D8,Ugrave:0x00D9,Uacute:0x00DA,Ucirc:0x00DB,
Uuml:0x00DC,Yacute:0x00DD,THORN:0x00DE,szlig:0x00DF,agrave:0x00E0,aacute:0x00E1,acirc:0x00E2,atilde:0x00E3,
auml:0x00E4,aring:0x00E5,aelig:0x00E6,ccedil:0x00E7,egrave:0x00E8,eacute:0x00E9,ecirc:0x00EA,euml:0x00EB,
igrave:0x00EC,iacute:0x00ED,icirc:0x00EE,iuml:0x00EF,eth:0x00F0,ntilde:0x00F1,ograve:0x00F2,oacute:0x00F3,
ocirc:0x00F4,otilde:0x00F5,ouml:0x00F6,divide:0x00F7,oslash:0x00F8,ugrave:0x00F9,uacute:0x00FA,ucirc:0x00FB,
uuml:0x00FC,yacute:0x00FD,thorn:0x00FE,yuml:0x00FF,OElig:0x0152,oelig:0x0153,Scaron:0x0160,scaron:0x0161,
Yuml:0x0178,fnof:0x0192,circ:0x02C6,tilde:0x02DC,Alpha:0x0391,Beta:0x0392,Gamma:0x0393,Delta:0x0394,
Epsilon:0x0395,Zeta:0x0396,Eta:0x0397,Theta:0x0398,Iota:0x0399,Kappa:0x039A,Lambda:0x039B,Mu:0x039C,
Nu:0x039D,Xi:0x039E,Omicron:0x039F,Pi:0x03A0,Rho:0x03A1,Sigma:0x03A3,Tau:0x03A4,Upsilon:0x03A5,
Phi:0x03A6,Chi:0x03A7,Psi:0x03A8,Omega:0x03A9,alpha:0x03B1,beta:0x03B2,gamma:0x03B3,delta:0x03B4,
epsilon:0x03B5,zeta:0x03B6,eta:0x03B7,theta:0x03B8,iota:0x03B9,kappa:0x03BA,lambda:0x03BB,mu:0x03BC,
nu:0x03BD,xi:0x03BE,omicron:0x03BF,pi:0x03C0,rho:0x03C1,sigmaf:0x03C2,sigma:0x03C3,tau:0x03C4,
upsilon:0x03C5,phi:0x03C6,chi:0x03C7,psi:0x03C8,omega:0x03C9,thetasym:0x03D1,upsih:0x03D2,piv:0x03D6,
ensp:0x2002,emsp:0x2003,thinsp:0x2009,zwnj:0x200C,zwj:0x200D,lrm:0x200E,rlm:0x200F,ndash:0x2013,
mdash:0x2014,lsquo:0x2018,rsquo:0x2019,sbquo:0x201A,ldquo:0x201C,rdquo:0x201D,bdquo:0x201E,dagger:0x2020,
Dagger:0x2021,bull:0x2022,hellip:0x2026,permil:0x2030,prime:0x2032,Prime:0x2033,lsaquo:0x2039,rsaquo:0x203A,
oline:0x203E,frasl:0x2044,euro:0x20AC,image:0x2111,weierp:0x2118,real:0x211C,trade:0x2122,alefsym:0x2135,
larr:0x2190,uarr:0x2191,rarr:0x2192,darr:0x2193,harr:0x2194,crarr:0x21B5,lArr:0x21D0,uArr:0x21D1,
rArr:0x21D2,dArr:0x21D3,hArr:0x21D4,forall:0x2200,part:0x2202,exist:0x2203,empty:0x2205,nabla:0x2207,
isin:0x2208,notin:0x2209,ni:0x220B,prod:0x220F,sum:0x2211,minus:0x2212,lowast:0x2217,radic:0x221A,
prop:0x221D,infin:0x221E,ang:0x2220,and:0x2227,or:0x2228,cap:0x2229,cup:0x222A,int:0x222B,
there4:0x2234,sim:0x223C,cong:0x2245,asymp:0x2248,ne:0x2260,equiv:0x2261,le:0x2264,ge:0x2265,
sub:0x2282,sup:0x2283,nsub:0x2284,sube:0x2286,supe:0x2287,oplus:0x2295,otimes:0x2297,perp:0x22A5,
sdot:0x22C5,lceil:0x2308,rceil:0x2309,lfloor:0x230A,rfloor:0x230B,lang:0x2329,rang:0x232A,loz:0x25CA,
spades:0x2660,clubs:0x2663,hearts:0x2665,diams:0x2666
};

var charToEntity = {};
for ( var entityName in entityToCode )
        charToEntity[String.fromCharCode(entityToCode[entityName])] = entityName;

function EscapeEntities(str) str.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, function(str) charToEntity[str] ? '&'+charToEntity[str]+';' : str );
```

```
function unescapeEntities(str) {
    return str.replace(
     /&(.+?);/g, 
     function(str, ent) {
        return String.fromCharCode( ent[0]!='#' ? entityToCode[ent] : ent[1]=='x' ? parseInt(ent.substr(2),16): parseInt(ent.substr(1)) );
     });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason this is happening is because the & in your string is being expanded into the ampersand entity by the browser.  To get around this, you'll need to convert the entities yourself.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="test"> </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

onload = function()
{
    var node = document.getElementById( 'test' );
    node.firstChild.nodeValue = convertEntities( 'Some &#187; entities &#171; and some &#187; more entities &#171;' );
}

function convertEntities( text )
{
    var matches = text.match( /\&\#(\d+);/g );

    for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ )
    {
        console.log( "Replacing: " + matches[i] );
        console.log( "With: " + convertEntity( matches[i] ) );
        text = text.replace( matches[i], convertEntity( matches[i] ) );
    }

    return text;

    function convertEntity( ent )
    {
        var num = parseInt(ent.replace(/\D/g, ''), 16);
        var esc = ((num < 16) ? '0' : '') + num.toString(16);
        return String.fromCharCode( esc );
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in other answers, I need to replace html encoded entities with javascript encoded ones. Starting from [BaileyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513112/setting-nodevalue-of-text-node-in-javascript-without-escaping/513277#513277), I've made this:

```
function convertEntities( text )
{
    var ret = text.replace( /\&\#(\d+);/g, function ( ent, captureGroup )
    {
        var num = parseInt( captureGroup );
        return String.fromCharCode( num );
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP **has entities / [entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)**, and wants them to appear in the DOM in a text node.

That's why the accepted answer and many [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513277/1175496) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965160/1175496) are great; those answers *convert entities to their **unicode equivalents** [using Javascript unicode escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode)*.

But I had a different need, I **had unicode characters** and I want to put them into the text node **as entity references**. I want entity references specifically so that the XML string representing my document **could be encoded in ASCII** (i.e. `encoding="ascii"`). Otherwise, as [@Bjorn said, the Unicode characters would be "decoded as junk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513112/setting-nodevalue-of-text-node-in-javascript-when-string-contains-html-entities#comment40906893_513172)

This is what I want, note the ASCII encoding:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<html>
<body>
    &#8220;Quotes&#8221;
</body>
</html>
```

The ASCII encoded XML/HTML above looks good in a browser:

[image: ASCII encoded XML/HTML using entity references for double quotes “ and ” renders as expected in a browser]

So I can't use the other answers because they insert unicode characters (but I want ASCII).

And I can't use the DOM text node API to insert **unescaped** entity references. As the OP points out: if you use DOM text node API to set the node's [`textContent` or `nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) DOM will [always escape any entities you try to inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360628/does-the-spec-require-that-setting-innertext-textcontent-of-node-automatically-e)...

- ...so `&` becomes `&amp;`
- ... and `&#8220;` becomes `&amp;#8220;`

As a deleted answer suggested, you could try to manipulate HTML directly using `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`, but **the [`Text` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) does not have those properties**.

Even if you are working on a non-Text node (like a `<span>`), the DOM API
in my browser won't leave the entities intact, the entities are "parsed"/dereferenced to their utf-8 strings like `&#8220;` becomes `“`

```
temp1.innerHTML='&#8220;'
'&#8220;'  // note how I set 
temp1.innerHTML;
'“'        // note how the unicode character comes back out; not the entity reference
```

But I want my document to be ASCII encoded, I can't use the UTF-8 characters  as set by the DOM; `“` and `”` will be "decoded as junk" as shown below:

[image: ASCII encoded XML/HTML using characters “ and ”; gets "decoded as junk" in a browser]

Yes I could simply use utf-8 encoding and therefore I don't need entity references (example shown below), but I **prefer to respect the original encoding (which happened to be ASCII)**.

[image: utf-8 encoded XML/HTML using characters “ and ”; renders as expected in the browser, but I don't want utf-8 encoding!]

So if you are only using DOM, there's no good way to put unescaped entity references into the text nodes, they are either escaped or dereferenced to utf-8 behavior. I think this is [as-designed/expected behavior](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/641#issuecomment-19242926), and I appreciate that... If you're only manipulating the DOM to change what renders in your browser, this might be no problem.

But in my case I was using the DOM to create and download an XML document, so I had an opportunity to get the `outerHTML` string and **manipulate it independently of the DOM API** before downloading it.

I get the `outerHTML` and run the function below to convert [non-ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters) characters to their entity equivalents ([similar approach in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)). **By replacing the non-ASCII with entity references, my document could be encoded as ASCII and read without problems.**

```
const replaceNonAsciiWithNumCharRefEntity = (s) => {

    return (s || '')
        .replace(
            /[^\x00-\x7F]/g,
            _ => `&#${_.codePointAt(0)};`
        );
}
```