# (grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters?

Tags: regex, unicode, grep, ascii, non-ascii-characters

On Linux, I have a directory with lots of files. Some of them have non-ASCII characters, but they are all valid [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). One program has a bug that prevents it working with non-ASCII filenames, and I have to find out how many are affected. I was going to do this with `find` and then do a [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to print the non-ASCII characters, and then do a `wc -l` to find the number. It doesn't have to be grep; I can use any standard Unix [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), like [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), etc.

However, is there a regular expression for 'any character that's not an ASCII character'?

Comment: Paul, yes I can use perl

Comment: `/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]`

Answer (score 378, accepted):

This will match a single non-ASCII character:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]
```

This is a valid [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (*Perl-Compatible Regular Expression*).

You can also use the [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shorthands:

- `[[:ascii:]]` - matches a single ASCII char
- `[^[:ascii:]]` - matches a single non-ASCII char

---

`[^[:print:]]` will probably suffice for you.**

Comment: @adrianm: No, `^` is valid in PCRE.

Comment: That's exactly right. However you have to use pcregrep, not standard grep. [^[:print:]] won't work if your terminal is set up in UTF8.

Comment: @Rory, why `:print:` won't work in a UTF8 terminal? This works for me in pry in a UTF8 terminal: `27.chr =~ /[^[:print:]]/`

Comment: This is really nice for fixing bad filenames - `rename 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' *` (you can use `-n` to check the renames are ok first).

Comment: How do I match any character that is non-UTF8 and any other specific characters?

Comment: Hmm powershell or .net doesn't support `[[:ascii:]]`.  And `\P{IsBasicLatin}` fails with the letter `i`.

Comment: Are non-ASCII characters considered non-printable?

Answer (score 42):

No, `[^\x20-\x7E]` is not ASCII.

This is real ASCII:

```
 [^\x00-\x7F]
```

Otherwise, it will trim out newlines and other special characters that are part of the ASCII table!

Answer (score 8):

You could also to check this page: [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), as it contains some useful Unicode characters classes, like:

```
\p{Control}: an ASCII 0x00..0x1F or Latin-1 0x80..0x9F control character.
```

Comment: [standard grep does not support those](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

Answer (score 4):

I use `[^\t\r\n\x20-\x7E]+` and that seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
[^\w \xC0-\xFF]
```

Case ask, the options is **Multiline**.

Answer (score 3):

`[^\x00-\x7F]` and `[^[:ascii:]]` miss some control bytes so [strings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) can be the better option sometimes. For example `cat test.torrent | perl -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]+/\n/g'` will do odd things to your terminal, where as `strings test.torrent` will behave.

Answer (score 3):

To Validate Text Box Accept Ascii Only use this Pattern

`[\x00-\x7F]+`

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a regex.

```
printf "%s\n" *[!\ -~]*
```

This will show file names with control characters in their names, too, but I consider that a feature.

If you don't have any matching files, the glob will expand to just itself, unless you have `nullglob` set. (The expression does not match itself, so technically, this output is unambiguous.)

Comment: Belatedly, I can observe that this *does* work correctly if you actually have some files which match this pattern. The behavior where the pattern prints itself when there are no matches is slightly surprising but actually correct. I edited the answer to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: Note that the behaviour depends on the current bash settings. I would recommend `shopt -s nullglob dotglob globasciiranges` to skip the non-matching patterns, to include the dotted filenames like `.tmp§` and not to depend on the current locale. I mean setting it temporarily just for this particular command, otherwise the default settings are fine.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be very flexible and extensible.
$field =~ s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g ;  # thus all non ASCII or specific items in question could be cleaned.  Very nice either in selection or pre-processing of items that will eventually become hash keys.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a non-ASCII string uppercase and lowercase:
[\W\w]+