# Regular expression for allowed characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to check, if the string in my PHP code contains only a specified list of characters. But as some of them might need scape, i just can't get it to work. I have tried everything, but it just doesen't work...

The required validation is:

- 0-9
- A-Z
- a-z
- chars: .%^&*()$#@!/*-+/

Basicaly, i want to check if there is an unknown ascii character (i don't know if there is a function to do that already).

My code is like this now:

```
if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9\.\#\-\+\*\\\/\=\_\%\$\(\)]/", $cmd) === false)
```

So, all of the chars are special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing a `*` at the end of the regexp. Also you could instead have the set expressed like `[\x00-\x7F]` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)).

This should work:

```
[\x00-\x7F]*
```

Comment: chars 0 to 7F are 'human readable'? is that why? @juan.facorro

Comment: No, they're not all human readable. Character 0 is the NULL character, and the rest are on an ASCII table.

Comment: nice... i will test this way also! Thanks

Comment: @Ivan And it will match **many, many more** characters than in your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, all of those characters are not special. If you're unsure, you can let PHP do the escaping for you with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
$regex = '/[A-Za-z0-9' . preg_quote( '.%^&()$#@!/-+/', '/') . ']+/';
if( !preg_match( $regex, $cmd))
```

Also, [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) returns an `int`, and you're doing `===` on a boolean, which will never hold true, since they will never be of the same type. You can simply check for `if( !preg_match())`.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that PHP has a function that scaped things! Thanks! Worked perfecly...

Answer (score 0):

`if(preg_match("/[.%^&()$#@!/+-a-zA-Z\d\s]+/", $cmd) === false)`
and if you need anchors `if(preg_match("/^[.%^&()$#@!/+-a-zA-Z\d\s]+$/", $cmd) === false)`