# Eclipse - Unicode playing cards

Tags: eclipse, unicode, playing-cards

I tried all text file encoding in Eclipse IDE Mars but the Eclipse IDE doesn't display [Unicode Playing Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode). I think that Eclipse IDE doesn't support this. Is there anything i can do, so that i will be able to display such?

0x1f0c1 = Ace Diamond

The eclipse IDE console just print nothing.

I wonder the computer specs has to do with this so here is my laptop's specs:
Windows 7 32-bit Ultimate

Thank you.

**EDIT: I think this has something to do with my laptop. My laptop shows squares only when i look up the link above. Ive tried in other laptop, the wikipedia shows the card not squares.**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to split the unicode into a surrogate pair, at least when using Java. So `U+1F0C1` becomes `\uD83C\uDCC1`.

The Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("\uD83C\uDCC1");
}
```

produced  for me in the eclipse console using `UTF-8` encoding.

References:

- [How to display 5 digit unicode characters such as a speaker /u1f50a in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557026/how-to-display-5-digit-unicode-characters-such-as-a-speaker-u1f50a-in-android)
- http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm

**Update:**

This issue is definitely OS-dependent (or at least font and encoding dependent). The above example works fine on a `UTF-8` based Linux platform, but does not render properly for Windows 7 which uses `UTF-16` internally. Neither the output from the code example above, nor viewing the Wiki article renders the playing cards properly on Windows 7 with my setup.

Comment: I only saw a square not a card.

Comment: Then they're probably not in your font.