# Why isn't Java properly displaying unicode in the String?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I was trying to print a `string` that has unicode for a skier **U+26F7** and for a runner **U+1F3C3** with the following code:

```
System.out.println("\u26f7" + "   " + "\u1f3c3");
```

Only the skier displays properly. However, IntelliJ does show the last 3 of the runner code with different color, indicating that there was a problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Your second character has 5 digits, which is not possible in java, but there is a workaround here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557026/how-to-display-5-digit-unicode-characters-such-as-a-speaker-u1f50a-in-android So in your case \uD83C\uDFC3 should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Java uses utf16 so the character `\u1f3c3` is out of its range. You can pass in the character using it's surroget pair

```
System.out.println("\u26f7" + "   " + "\ud83c\udfc3")
```

Comment: the question is about Java and not Javascript

Comment: It still doesn't show them: a small rectangle is being shown for both of them instead.

Comment: @cellpowerhouse In that case, your console character set doesn't support that specific character.

Answer (score 0):

Java’s escape syntax was designed back when Unicode was expected to have no more than 2<sup>16</sup> characters, so you must specify exactly four hex digits ater the `\u`.  No more, no less.

`"\u1f3c3"` is actually the two characters `\u1f3c` and `3`.

Java Strings are *always* in UTF-16.  So one option is to look up detailed information for your character (for instance, [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3c3/index.htm)) and use the corresponding UTF-16 values in your string: 0xD83C 0xDFC3 → `"\uD83C\uDFC3"`

Another option is using the `%c` specifier in [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dchar).  For example:

```
System.out.printf("%c   %c%n", 0x26f7, 0x1f3c3);
```

(Unlike println, printf does not print a newline unless you add `%n` to the format.)

Comment: It also doesn't work. Must be something with my system then (I'm using Linux).

Comment: Have you verified that the U+1F3C3 character is visible in any font? That fileformat.info page should show the character in the first two lines of the **Java Data** table.  Or, you can try running gedit and typing Ctrl-Shift-U 1f3c3 <space> in the editor.

Comment: it only shows the skier, same as in intellij idea. I also tried to paste in vim and I got the same result. My system just won't display unicode outside 0xffff :|