# Replace non-ASCII characters with their Unicode code points when they have a 5+ digit Unicode code

Tags: javascript, regex, string, unicode

I want to create a JS script that can identify non-ASCII characters in a string and replace them with their corresponding Unicode code points (i.e. `Lorem ipsum á dolor sit amet` becomes `Lorem ipsum [00E1] sit amet`). I've already created a basic program for doing so, but I've noticed that it interprets characters with more than 5 digits in their code point (e.g. , which is Unicode U+1D538) as two separate characters:

```js
function findNonAsciiCodes(string) {
  let k = string.replace(/[^ -~]/g, x => `[${x.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(4, '0')}]`);
  console.log(k)
}
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ispum á dolor sit amet") // with 4 digit unicode character: [00E1]
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet") // with 5 digit unicode character: [D835][DD38] - undesired
```

After some digging on StackOverflow, I've found that Java/JS cannot easily Unicode characters with more than 4 digits in their code point - instead having to represent them with a "surrogate pair" of 2 characters ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557026/how-to-display-5-digit-unicode-characters-such-as-a-speaker-u1f50a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557026/how-to-display-5-digit-unicode-characters-such-as-a-speaker-u1f50a)).

I want to find a way to, ideally using `string.replace()` and no for loops, find the proper code points for these characters; however, when using `string.replace()`, it seems to produce two separate strings rather than creating an array (i.e. `"".replace(/[^ -~]/g, x => console.log(x.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()))` prints `D835` and `DD38` separately).

I have noticed that matching both characters of the surrogate pair at once produces the desired result (the full 5 digit code), but I don't know how to create regex that can distinguish between surrogate pair members and neighboring non-ASCII characters; in the example below - which matches between 1 and 2 non-ascii characters to try and catch surrogate pairs - 4 digit code non-ASCII characters can "blend" with other non-ASCII characters immediately succeeding them, including surrogate pair characters:

```js
function findNonAsciiCodes(string) {
  let k = string.replace(/[^ -~]{1,2}/g, x => `[${x.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(4, "0")}]`);
  // regex matches between 1 and 2 non-ascii characters at once
  console.log(k);
 }
 findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet"); // gives correct code ([1D538])
 findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum á dolor sit amet"); // still gives correct codes ([1D538][00E1])
 findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum áá dolor sit amet"); // 4 digit before 4 digit; ignores second character due to "blending" ([00E1])
 // ^ desired output: Lorem ispum [00E1][00E1] dolor sit amet
 findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum á dolor sit amet"); // 4 digit before 5 digit, gives incorrect codes due to "blending" ([00E1][DD38])
 // ^ desired output: Lorem ipsum [00E1][1D538] dolor sit amet
```

Is it possible to create a Regex expression capable of distinguishing between normal non-ASCII characters and surrogate pair characters, or use JS within the `.replace()` capable of "decoding" the surrogate pairs? If not, is it possible to achieve the desired result without `for` loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?![\x00-\uFFFF])./gu` to match any Unicode character point that does not belong to BMP plane:

```js
function findNonAsciiCodes(string) {
  let k = string.replace(/(?![\x00-\uFFFF])./gu, x => `[${x.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(4, "0")}]`);
  console.log(k);
}
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum  dolor sit amet"); // Lorem ipsum [1D538] dolor sit amet
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum á dolor sit amet"); // Lorem ipsum [1D538]á dolor sit amet
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum áá dolor sit amet"); // Lorem ipsum áá dolor sit amet
findNonAsciiCodes("Lorem ipsum á dolor sit amet"); // Lorem ipsum á[1D538] dolor sit amet
```