# Android - How to filter emoji (emoticons) from a string?

Tags: android, emoji

I'm working on an Android app, and I do not want people to use emoji in the input.

How can I remove emoji characters from a string?

Comment: Regular expressions are an option. Or if the list of emojis is well known, a simple list that you can iterate through and remove matches in your input would work well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013341/removing-characters-of-a-specific-unicode-range-from-a-string

Comment: You can use Character class
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366172/check-if-letter-is-emoji/41147459#41147459

Comment: @user2474486 That's not what was being asked here. The Character class can indeed recognize surrogate pairs, but that does not mean the character is an emoji. E.g. U+1D120 is not an emoji but is a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Emojis can be found in the following ranges ([**source**](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-6c-other-additional-symbols)) :

- U+2190 to U+21FF
- U+2600 to U+26FF
- U+2700 to U+27BF
- U+3000 to U+303F
- U+1F300 to U+1F64F
- U+1F680 to U+1F6FF

You can use this line in your script to filter them all at once:

`text.replace("/[\u2190-\u21FF]|[\u2600-\u26FF]|[\u2700-\u27BF]|[\u3000-\u303F]|[\u1F300-\u1F64F]|[\u1F680-\u1F6FF]/g", "");`

Comment: this is one potential answer but does not handle all cases. But nonetheless

Comment: @user210504 what cases does it not handle? It's not useful to say "this doesn't handle all cases" if you don't have an example.

Comment: \u expects 4 digits -- how is this supposed to work for 1f300 etc?

Comment: Not working. In the end I used https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java. For example, removing all emojis: EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis(text);

Answer (score 8):

Latest emoji data can be found here:

http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/

There is a folder named with emoji version.
As app developers a good idea is to use latest version available.

When You look inside a folder, You'll see text files in it.
You should check emoji-data.txt. It contains all standard emoji codes.

There are a lot of small symbol code ranges for emoji.
Best support will be to check all these in Your app.

Some people ask why there are 5 digit codes when we can only specify 4 after \u.
Well these are codes made from surrogate pairs. Usually 2 symbols are used to encode one emoji.

For example, we have a string.

```
String s = ...;
```

UTF-16 representation

```
byte[] utf16 = s.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

Iterate over UTF-16

```
for(int i = 0; i < utf16.length; i += 2) {
```

Get one char

```
char c = (char)((char)(utf16[i] & 0xff) << 8 | (char)(utf16[i + 1] & 0xff));
```

Now check for surrogate pairs. Emoji are located on the first plane, so check first part of pair in range 0xd800..0xd83f.

```
if(c >= 0xd800 && c <= 0xd83f) {
    high = c;
    continue;
}
```

For second part of surrogate pair range is 0xdc00..0xdfff. And we can now convert a pair to one 5 digit code.

```
else if(c >= 0xdc00 && c <= 0xdfff) {
    low = c;
    long unicode = (((long)high - 0xd800) * 0x400) + ((long)low - 0xdc00) + 0x10000;
}
```

All other symbols are not pairs so process them as is.

```
else {
    long unicode = c;
}
```

Now use data from emoji-data.txt to check if it's emoji.
If it is, then skip it. If not then copy bytes to output byte array.

Finally byte array is converted to String by

```
String out = new String(outarray, Charset.forName("UTF-16BE"));
```

Comment: P.S. If You want to remove some additional symbols, there are Unicode ranges can be found here: http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode.php

Comment: link seems broken to me :(

Comment: @jacoballenwood Works for me. try to Google "Unicode Character Ranges"

Comment: Here's the emoji-data.txt file for version 13.0.0: https://unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt. For next versions, go to https://unicode.org/Public/ > [version] > ucd > emoji

Answer (score 6):

For those using Kotlin, [Char.isSurrogate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-surrogate.html) can help as well. Find and remove the indexes that are true from that.

Comment: It wont help if the emoji is composed of more than one, such as skin coloured ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to remove emojis. Note: This only works on API 24 and forwards

```
public  String remove_Emojis_For_Devices_API_24_Onwards(String name)
   {
    // we will store all the non emoji characters in this array list
     ArrayList<Character> nonEmoji = new ArrayList<>();

    // this is where we will store the reasembled name
    String newName = "";

    //Character.UnicodeScript.of () was not added till API 24 so this is a 24 up solution
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        /* we are going to cycle through the word checking each character
         to find its unicode script to compare it against known alphabets*/
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            // currently emojis don't have a devoted unicode script so they return UNKNOWN
            if (!(Character.UnicodeScript.of(name.charAt(i)) + "").equals("UNKNOWN")) {
                nonEmoji.add(name.charAt(i));//its not an emoji so we add it
            }
        }
        // we then cycle through rebuilding the string
        for (int i = 0; i < nonEmoji.size(); i++) {
            newName += nonEmoji.get(i);
        }
    }
    return newName;
}
```

> so if we pass in a string:
>
> remove_Emojis_For_Devices_API_24_Onwards(" test  Indic:ढ Japanese:な  Korean:ㅂ");
>
> it returns: test Indic:ढ Japanese:な Korean:ㅂ
>
> Emoji placement or count doesn't matter

Comment: Really interesting but not perfect. This couldn't filter "❤" and "☤", which resides in dingbats  and miscellaneous symbols block.

Comment: @Jenix Those are not emojis

Comment: @Auras YES IT IS. See this. http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3Aemoji%3A%5D&g=emoji

Comment: Emoji spreads around here and there. That's why it's hard to filter all of them. You can find them in General Punctuation, Dingbats, Emoticons, Miscellaneous Symbols, Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs, Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs, Transport and Map Symbols blocks. As for "☤", I think that was typo or something but "❤" really is emoji.

Answer (score -1):

```
private String removeEmojis(String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c <= 127) {
            output.append(c);
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).