# Check if letter is emoji

Tags: java, regex, emoji

I want to check if a letter is a emoji. I've found some similiar questions on so and found this regex:

```
private final String emo_regex = "([\\u20a0-\\u32ff\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udeff\\udbb9\\udce5-\\udbb9\\udcee])";
```

However, when I do the following in a sentence like:

```
for (int k=0; k<letters.length;k++) {    
    if (letters[k].matches(emo_regex)) {
        emoticon.add(letters[k]);
    }
}
```

It doesn't add any letters with any emoji. I've also tried with a `Matcher` and a `Pattern`, but that didn't work either. Is there something wrong with the regex or am I missing something obvious in my code?

This is how I get the letter:

```
sentence = "Jij staat op 10 "
String[] letters = sentence.split("");
```

The last  should be recognized and added to `emoticon`

Comment: Can you show us more of the code? The loop seems alright...

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of the value of `letters` that you expect to match?  Also, what gives you confidence that the regex you found is definitely correct and comprehensive?

Comment: emojis have two letters if i am correct

Comment: I don't get your approach at all. Did you split your original string into a `String[]`, where each element is a single-character string, just to be able to apply a regex instead of plain Java numeric range check?

Comment: Edited the question to show how I get the letter guys!

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840667/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like those emojis are two characters long, but with `split("")` you are splitting between each single character, thus none of those letters can be the emoji you are looking for.

Instead, you could try splitting between words:

```
for (String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
    if (word.matches(emo_regex)) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

But of course this will miss emojis that are joined to a word, or punctuation.

Alternatively, you could just use a `Matcher` to `find` any `group` in the sentence that matches the regex.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(emo_regex).matcher(sentence);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is not recognizing  . It helps now that I know emoji's have 2 chars btw

Comment: @bdv Seems to work for me (using the second approach). Or is this supposed to be one single (composite) emoji?

Comment: @bdv Testing with `String sentence = "zing . It he";` (just copied from your comment), your pattern, and then the code starting with `Matcher`. It outputs two emojis.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [emoji4j](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) library. The following should solve the issue.

```
String htmlifiedText = EmojiUtils.htmlify(text);
// regex to identify html entitities in htmlified text
Matcher matcher = htmlEntityPattern.matcher(htmlifiedText);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String emojiCode = matcher.group();
    if (isEmoji(emojiCode)) {

        emojis.add(EmojiUtils.getEmoji(emojiCode).getEmoji());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This function I created checks if given String consists of only emojis.
in other words if the String contains any character not included in the Regex, it will return false.

```
private static boolean isEmoji(String message){
    return message.matches("(?:[\uD83C\uDF00-\uD83D\uDDFF]|[\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]|" +
            "[\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDE4F]|[\uD83D\uDE80-\uD83D\uDEFF]|" +
            "[\u2600-\u26FF]\uFE0F?|[\u2700-\u27BF]\uFE0F?|\u24C2\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}|" +
            "[\uD83C\uDD70\uD83C\uDD71\uD83C\uDD7E\uD83C\uDD7F\uD83C\uDD8E\uD83C\uDD91-\uD83C\uDD9A]\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA]\uFE0F?|[\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\u2934\u2935]\uFE0F?|[\u3030\u303D]\uFE0F?|[\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\uD83C\uDE01\uD83C\uDE02\uD83C\uDE1A\uD83C\uDE2F\uD83C\uDE32-\uD83C\uDE3A\uD83C\uDE50\uD83C\uDE51]\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\u203C\u2049]\uFE0F?|[\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE]\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\u00A9\u00AE]\uFE0F?|[\u2122\u2139]\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDC04\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDCCF\uFE0F?|" +
            "[\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA]\uFE0F?)+");
}
```

Example of implementation:

```
public static int detectEmojis(String message){
    int len = message.length(), NumEmoji = 0;
    // if the the given String is only emojis.
    if(isEmoji(message)){
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // if the charAt(i) is an emoji by it self -> ++NumEmoji
            if (isEmoji(message.charAt(i)+"")) {
                NumEmoji++;
            } else {
                // maybe the emoji is of size 2 - so lets check.
                if (i < (len - 1)) { // some Emojis are two characters long in java, e.g. a rocket emoji is "\uD83D\uDE80";
                    if (Character.isSurrogatePair(message.charAt(i), message.charAt(i + 1))) {
                        i += 1; //also skip the second character of the emoji
                        NumEmoji++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return NumEmoji;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

given is a function that runs on a string (of only emojis) and return the number of emojis in it. (with the help of other answers i found here on StackOverFlow).

Comment: I am familiar with regex, but that is so complex that I do not really understand what you are doing there.

Comment: Thanks for the regex, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Character** class for determining is letter is part of surrogate pair. There some helpful methods to deal with surrogate pairs emoji symbols, for example:

```
String text = "";
if (text.length() > 1 && Character.isSurrogatePair(text.charAt(0), text.charAt(1))) {
    int codePoint = Character.toCodePoint(text.charAt(0), text.charAt(1));
    char[] c = Character.toChars(codePoint);
}
```

Comment: **This doesn't work and shouldn't be used** because some emojis contain only one char, e.g. "☠".length() is 1. Should be voted down but not with its privilege of mine currently.

Comment: "☠" is not an emoji. It's just a symbol, but the system display it like an emoji. The value is 9760.

Comment: Characters for which `isSurrogatePair` returns true include non-emoji characters, such as ``.

Answer (score 4):

Try this project [simple-emoji-4j](https://github.com/liheyuan/simple-emoji-4j)

Compatible with Emoji 12.0 (2018.10.15)

Simple with:

```
EmojiUtils.containsEmoji(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how Telegram does it:

```
private static boolean isEmoji(String message){
    return message.matches("(?:[\uD83C\uDF00-\uD83D\uDDFF]|[\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]|" +
        "[\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDE4F]|[\uD83D\uDE80-\uD83D\uDEFF]|" +
        "[\u2600-\u26FF]\uFE0F?|[\u2700-\u27BF]\uFE0F?|\u24C2\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDD70\uD83C\uDD71\uD83C\uDD7E\uD83C\uDD7F\uD83C\uDD8E\uD83C\uDD91-\uD83C\uDD9A]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA]\uFE0F?|[\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u2934\u2935]\uFE0F?|[\u3030\u303D]\uFE0F?|[\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\uD83C\uDE01\uD83C\uDE02\uD83C\uDE1A\uD83C\uDE2F\uD83C\uDE32-\uD83C\uDE3A\uD83C\uDE50\uD83C\uDE51]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u203C\u2049]\uFE0F?|[\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE]\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u00A9\u00AE]\uFE0F?|[\u2122\u2139]\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDC04\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDCCF\uFE0F?|" +
        "[\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA]\uFE0F?)+");
}
```

It is [Line 21,026](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DrKLO/Telegram/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/ChatActivity.java) in ChatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth bearing in mind that Java code can be written in Unicode. So you *can* just do:

```
@Test
public void containsEmoji_detects_smileys() {
    assertTrue(containsEmoji("This  is a smiley "));
    assertTrue(containsEmoji("This  is a different smiley"));
    assertFalse(containsEmoji("No smiley here"));
}

private boolean containsEmoji(String s) {
    String pattern = ".*[].*";
    return s.matches(pattern);
}
```

Although see: [Should source code be saved in UTF-8 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178348/should-source-code-be-saved-in-utf-8-format) for discussion on whether that's a good idea.

---

You can split a String into Unicode codepoints in Java 8 using `String.codePoints()`, which returns an `IntStream`. That means you can do something like:

```
Set<Integer> emojis = new HashSet<>();
emojis.add("".codePointAt(0));
emojis.add("".codePointAt(0));
String s = "1345";
s.codePoints().forEach( codepoint -> {
    System.out.println(
        new String(Character.toChars(codepoint)) 
        + " " 
        + emojis.contains(codepoint));
});
```

... prints ...

```
1 false
 true
3 false
4 false
 true
5 false
```

Of course if you prefer not to have literal unicode chars in your code you can just put numbers in your set:

```
emojis.add(0x1F601);
```

Comment: What a crappy attitude in the previous comment. This answer has some good insights (using codePoints). However it's only a workable solution for catching specific emoji, since you would need every emoji in the regex if you wanted it to filter any possible emoji

Answer (score 1):

Unicode has [an entire document](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/) on this.  Emojis and emoji sequences are a lot more complicated than just a few character ranges.  There are emoji modifiers (for example, skin tones), regional indicator pairs (country flags), and some special sequences like the pirate flag.

You can use Unicode’s [emoji data files](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/15.0/) to reliably find emoji characters and emoji sequences.  This will work even as new complex emojis are added:

```
import java.net.URL;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class EmojiCollector {
    private static String emojiSequencesBaseURI;

    private final Pattern emojiPattern;

    public EmojiCollector()
    throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sequences = new StringBuilder();

        appendSequencesFrom(
            uriOfEmojiSequencesFile("emoji-sequences.txt"),
            sequences);
        appendSequencesFrom(
            uriOfEmojiSequencesFile("emoji-zwj-sequences.txt"),
            sequences);

        emojiPattern = Pattern.compile(sequences.toString());
    }

    private void appendSequencesFrom(String sequencesFileURI,
                                     StringBuilder sequences)
    throws IOException {
        Path sequencesFile = download(sequencesFileURI);

        Pattern range =
            Pattern.compile("^(\\p{XDigit}{4,6})\\.\\.(\\p{XDigit}{4,6})");
        Matcher rangeMatcher = range.matcher("");

        try (BufferedReader sequencesReader =
            Files.newBufferedReader(sequencesFile)) {

            String line;
            while ((line = sequencesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.trim().isEmpty() || line.startsWith("#")) {
                    continue;
                }

                int semicolon = line.indexOf(';');
                if (semicolon < 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                String codepoints = line.substring(0, semicolon);

                if (sequences.length() > 0) {
                    sequences.append("|");
                }

                if (rangeMatcher.reset(codepoints).find()) {
                    String start = rangeMatcher.group(1);
                    String end = rangeMatcher.group(2);

                    sequences.append("[\\x{").append(start).append("}");
                    sequences.append("-\\x{").append(end).append("}]");
                } else {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(codepoints);
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        String codepoint = scanner.next();
                        sequences.append("\\x{").append(codepoint).append("}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static String uriOfEmojiSequencesFile(String baseName)
    throws IOException {
        if (emojiSequencesBaseURI == null) {
            URL readme = new URL(
                "https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ReadMe.txt");
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(readme.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith("Public/emoji/")) {
                        emojiSequencesBaseURI =
                            "https://www.unicode.org/" + line.trim();
                        if (!emojiSequencesBaseURI.endsWith("/")) {
                            emojiSequencesBaseURI += "/";
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (emojiSequencesBaseURI == null) {
                // Where else can we get this reliably?
                String version = "15.0";

                emojiSequencesBaseURI =
                    "https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/" + version + "/";
            }
        }

        return emojiSequencesBaseURI + baseName;
    }

    private static Path download(String uri)
    throws IOException {

        Path cacheDir;
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
        if (os.contains("Windows")) {
            Path appDataDir;
            String appData = System.getenv("APPDATA");
            if (appData != null) {
                appDataDir = Paths.get(appData);
            } else {
                appDataDir = Paths.get(home, "AppData");
            }

            cacheDir = appDataDir.resolve("Local");
        } else if (os.contains("Mac")) {
            cacheDir = Paths.get(home, "Library", "Application Support");
        } else {
            cacheDir = Paths.get(home, ".cache");
            String cacheHome = System.getenv("XDG_CACHE_HOME");
            if (cacheHome != null) {
                Path dir = Paths.get(cacheHome);
                if (dir.isAbsolute()) {
                    cacheDir = dir;
                }
            }
        }

        String baseName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        Path dataDir = cacheDir.resolve(EmojiCollector.class.getName());
        Path dataFile = dataDir.resolve(baseName);
        if (!Files.isReadable(dataFile)) {
            Files.createDirectories(dataDir);
            URL dataURL = new URL(uri);
            try (InputStream data = dataURL.openStream()) {
                Files.copy(data, dataFile);
            }
        }

        return dataFile;
    }

    public Collection<String> getEmojisIn(String letters) {
        Collection<String> emoticons = new ArrayList<>();

        Matcher emojiMatcher = emojiPattern.matcher(letters);
        while (emojiMatcher.find()) {
            emoticons.add(emojiMatcher.group());
        }

        return emoticons;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {
        EmojiCollector collector = new EmojiCollector();

        for (String arg : args) {
            Collection<String> emojis = collector.getEmojisIn(arg);
            System.out.println(arg + " => " + String.join("", emojis));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some java logic that relies on java.lang.Character api that I have found pretty reliably tells apart an emoji from mere 'special characters' and non-latin alphabets. Give it a try.

```
import static java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS;
import static java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_TECHNICAL;
import static java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock.VARIATION_SELECTORS;
import static java.lang.Character.codePointAt;
import static java.lang.Character.codePointBefore;
import static java.lang.Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint;
import static java.lang.Character.isValidCodePoint;

public boolean checkStringEmoji(String someString) {
    if(!someString.isEmpty() && someString.length() < 5) {
        int firstCodePoint = codePointAt(someString, 0);
        int lastCodePoint = codePointBefore(someString, someString.length());
        if (isValidCodePoint(firstCodePoint) && isValidCodePoint(lastCodePoint)) {
            if (isSupplementaryCodePoint(firstCodePoint) ||
                isSupplementaryCodePoint(lastCodePoint) ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(firstCodePoint) == MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(firstCodePoint) == MISCELLANEOUS_TECHNICAL ||
                Character.UnicodeBlock.of(lastCodePoint) == VARIATION_SELECTORS
            ) {
                // string is emoji
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 21 added `Character::isEmoji` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isEmoji(int))). For example:

```
String sentence = "This string contains 1 emoji !";
sentence.codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isEmoji)
    .filter(emoji -> !Character.isEmojiComponent(emoji))
    .mapToObj(Character::toString)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

These new methods can also be accessed in regex through [property constructs](https://inside.java/2023/11/20/sip089/):

```
Pattern.compile("\\p{IsEmoji}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

```
for (String word : sentence.split("")) {
    if (word.matches(emo_regex)) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```