# How can I find and count emojis?

Tags: python

I want to count the emojis in the text the same as I do it with the hashtags in the next function:

```
import emoji
def count_sent(text):
   t = re.sub('#[\w]*', 'hashtag', 'text')
   return(t.count('hashtag'))
```

How can I build it into this function and get this output: return(t.count('hashtag'),t.count('emoji'))

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28366172/1639625 (for Java, but the regex from the question should work here, too)

Comment: Also, don't replace with `hashtag` and then count `hashtag`. What if that word appears in the text? Instead, just count the matches in `re.findall` or `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 1):

The [emoji module](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) that you are importing on your first line has a function [emoji_count()](https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/docs/api.html#emoji.emoji_count)

```py
import emoji
print(emoji.emoji_count('text  with emoji '))
# 2
```