# How can I strip undisplayable characters from a string with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I have a feed that pulls from social feeds. These feeds can sometimes include special characters such as emojis that don't translate well:

[image]

I just want to strip out any characters that can't be displayed. I know that might remove a few that I could want but that's fine. I know I can do a `regex` but not really sure how to target like what's in the photo.

---EDIT---

This is what is throwing the characters above:

[image]

Comment: *can't be displayed* Well you would need to specify that a bit clearer. (^^ Seems more like an encoding problem)

Comment: I added an edit. the plan is throwing those characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178349/android-how-to-filter-emoji-emoticons-from-a-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497885/remove-control-characters-from-php-string

Answer (score 2):

Try using [PHP Sanitize Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php), most specifically FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS

```
<?php
$a = 'text including "unprintable" characters';
$sanitized_a = filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
echo $sanitized_a;
?>
```

Just be careful using this if there are some characters you want (like `<` and `>` for instance)! Check the link at the top for a full list of filters you can choose from.