# How to judge a string contains emoji character in java,and how to filter it

Tags: java

android and ios client call a interface with emoji character,but mysql database encoding is utf8 (motify to utf8mb4 is not allowed).  How to filter emoji character  ?
I want to use unicode Regex,i think is not perfect.
I has read some java code like this link http://www.cocoachina.com/ios/20160527/16494.html
,but not yet achieving the desired results,has better tools or idea to fix it?

Comment: Instead of getting rid of emojis, how about url encode the string?

Comment: utf8 is format for serialization of Unicode text. It should handle all Unicode symbols. You may want to check which version of Unicode is supported in your DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to filter emoji (emoticons) from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178349/android-how-to-filter-emoji-emoticons-from-a-string)

Comment: it not database problem,the program is online.  UTF-8Unicode maxlen is 3,insert to databse shows 'Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x84' for column '

Comment: thanks,@hnefatl. what about ios?

Comment: @YuJia The idea behind the top answer in that post is language-agnostic. The implementation is given in Java, but it won't be hard to implement in whichever language you're using for your iOS app.