# Regex. Find all words with non latin characters

Tags: c++, c, regex, locale

How can I find all words with at least one non latin letter (arabic, chinese...) in them using regex.h library?

cityدبي

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters and its answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
(?=\pL)(?![a-zA-Z])
```

This will match a letter in any alphabet that is not a latin letter:

```
not ok - cityدبي
ok - city
not ok - دبي
```

Comment: Won't this match latin characters with accents, like ąęśćżół?
I have to say that I'm quite irritated by how some English-speaking people apparently treat accented latin letters as second-class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[a-zA-Z]*[^A-Za-z \d]+[a-zA-Z]*
```

Means   : One or more non latin letter preceded or followed by one or more latin letter i.e. a word containing atleast 1 non latin character.
See demo with some random text:
http://regexr.com?326s3

You may need to adjust this regex to your needs,and include things like digits,special characters,word boundaries as per your input.

Answer (score -1):

just use `[^a-zA-Z]`
if not match, it should contain an international character...

Comment: -1 or a space, or a period ... Depends on the locale and encoding anyway.

Comment: @tripleee I think regex.h support unicode. And I dont think we need a more complicated regular expression to distinct a pure latin word...