# Regular Expression for Non-Alphanumeric, Non-Symbol Characters

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a simple form pre-validator. I am looking for a PHP regular expression to match any *irregular* symbols. That is, non-Latic and non-numeric characters, and charachters which are not included in normal English punctuation (basically, match characters not in the second through forth column on [this ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). Any regexp wizards out there who could help me out?

Comment: did you search? look at the related list to the right

Comment: I did, I was unable to find anything. Usually Googling is faster - I do in fact try that first.

Comment: I find that hard to believe, but then i find a lot of what other people do hard to believe.

Comment: confusing the uses of "regular" are not likely to lead to targeted results.

Comment: Ah, sorry, ever since Watson premiered on Jeopardy I just assume that every computer knows everything about whatever I'm saying. Thanks for the advice @MattWhipple, I'll change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second to fourth column can be translated into a simple regexp:

```
/[^ -~]/
```

matches any characters not between space and tilde.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer is over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)

The long & short of this.  This PCRE: `[^\x00-\x7F]`

Comment: I wouldn't expect `\0` or an ASCII `BEL` in normal English punctuation.

Comment: Don't you `BEL`'ing believe it!