# Why does this Bash regex match return an Exit Status of "2"?

Tags: regex, bash, posix

I'm writing a Bash script that needs to scan for the existence of non-ASCII characters in filenames. I'm using the POSIX bracket regex syntax to match the non-ASCII characters, but for some reason, when I test for the match in an if/then statement, the test always returns an Exit Status of 2, and never matches my test string.

Here's the code in question:

```
FILEREQ_SOURCEFILE="Filename–WithNonASćII-Charàcters-05sec_23.98.mov"
REGEX_MATCH_NONASCII="[^[:ascii:]]"

if [[ $FILEREQ_SOURCEFILE =~ $REGEX_MATCH_NONASCII ]]; then

        echo "Exit Status: $?"
        echo "Matched!"

    else
        echo "Exit Status: $?"
        echo "No Match"
fi
```

This code always returns:

```
Exit Status: 2
No Match
```

I've read and re-read the [bash-hackers.org explanation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching) of how regex matching works, as well as [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters) on SO regarding matching non-ASCII characters, but for the life of me, I can't get this to work. What am I missing here?

I'm running this under Bash 3.2, on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: Which character is non ASCII in your filename?

Comment: The first "–" (it's an en-dash, not a hyphen), the "ć" and the "à".

Comment: The funny thing is that if I simplify this by changing the regex to match on *any* ASCII character ([[:ascii:]], instead of [^[:ascii:]]), and change $FILEREQ_SOURCEFILE to something simple like "Filename.mov", I still get the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page, **SHELL GRAMMAR** section, **Compound Commands** subsection, `[[ expression ]]` subsubsection:

> If the regular expression is syntactically incorrect,  the  conditional expression's return value is 2.

From the `regex(7)` man page:

> Standard character class names are:
>
> ```
>           alnum   digit   punct
>           alpha   graph   space
>           blank   lower   upper
>           cntrl   print   xdigit
> ```

There is no "ascii" in there. Perhaps you should try `[\0-\x7f]` instead (or `[^\0-\x7f]` as the case may be).

Comment: +1; quibble: on OS X, you must use `man re_format` (`man 7 regex` won't work, and `man regex` will show you `regex(3)`).