# Remove all rows with a special character in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a dataframe where there are special characters (like a square) in one of the columns `EPI_ID`. I want to remove all rows that contain this special character. This isn't a standard character and I haven't found issues similar to this in a dataframe, mostly as strings. Nevertheless, I am having trouble identifying these columns. Any suggestions?

df

```
EPI_ID    stuff
2342F     randoM_words
FER43     predictive_words
u'\u25A1' blank
```

My attempt:

```
df[~df['EPI_ID'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii') == True)]
```

My results are throwing False for every row.

Expected output:

```
EPI_ID    stuff
2342F     randoM_words
FER43     predictive_words
```

Edit: the square doesn't come up in the mock df. But this is what it is [square](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm)

Comment: the example doesnot have a square, also please post the expected output. Thanks

Comment: SOF not allowing me to show the 'square' ...

Comment: What is it ASCII code?

Comment: its a unicode character from what I understand

Comment: added a link in the question to show the character.

Comment: `j[~j['EPI_ID'].apply(lambda x: x.encode('ascii') == b'\x1a')]` --> this works to remove the row if I specifically select that character.

Comment: Please include/paste the first 5 rows that demonstrate this issue.

Comment: @MartinBobak how this works: `df.EPI_ID.str.replace('\W', '')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `DataFrame` looks something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'EPI_ID': ['2343F', 'FER43', 'DF' + u'\u25A1' + '123', 'PQRX74'], 'STUFF': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']})

>>> df

   EPI_ID STUFF
0   2343F   abc
1   FER43   def
2  DF□123   ghi
3  PQRX74   jkl
```

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), which handles regex:

```
df.loc[df['EPI_ID'].str.contains(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+') == False]

   EPI_ID STUFF
0   2343F   abc
1   FER43   def
3  PQRX74   jkl
```

Regex courtesy of this answer: [(grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)