# How to separate a mixed word (Persian and English) in python

Tags: python, nlp

Hi i have a dataset of strings, and some strings have mixed words such as below:

```
    سلام12World
    دوربینdigital
    سال2012good
```

...
and my desired output is :

```
   12 سلام world
   دوربین digital
   2012 سال good
```

here is my code :

```
 def spliteKeyWord(str):
     regex = r"[\u200b-\u200c]|[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+\'*[a-z]*"
     matches = re.findall(regex, str, re.UNICODE)
     return matches
```

but this code doesnt show my desired output. Is it possible to get something like that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern:

```
def spliteKeyWord(s):
    return re.findall(r'[\dA-Za-z]+|[^\dA-Za-z\W]+', s, re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, Does this function work on a text column of a DataFrame?

Comment: I believe the `str.methods` in `pandas` support regex, so it should work.

Comment: I tested this function it is correct but when there is a word like 'Iphone6' this function convert this word to 'Iphone','6'

Comment: @getdata I've updated my answer so that numbers and English alphabets are grouped together instead.

Comment: Dear @blhsing, your code doesn't consider punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters), you can use this regex to parse non-ascii characters:

```
words = ['12سلامWorld','دوربینdigital','2012سالgood']

for w in words:
    re.split(r'([^\x00-\x7F]+)', w)


# ['12', 'سلام', 'World']
# ['', 'دوربین', 'digital']
# ['2012', 'سال', 'good']
```

This will split everything between the non-ascii words.