# Finding non-ascii encoded characters in an R package

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, package

I've recently made a series of edits to source and documentation code to an R package, and when I attempt to render documentation (using `devtools::check_man()`) I receive the error:

*'DESCRIPTION' file has an 'Encoding' field and re-encoding is not possible*

As far as I can tell, this indicates that I have included some non-ASCII characters somewhere in the source code of my package.

How can I track down the problematic characters?

I've tried using RStudio's "find in files" with the regular expression `[^\x00-\x7F]` (per [(grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)), but this matches almost every line of my code.

slava-kohut suggests (in comments)

```r
lapply(list.files(include.dirs=FALSE, full.names=TRUE, no..=TRUE), 
       tools::showNonASCIIfile)
```

This finds a non-ASCII character in a file that's included in `.Rbuildignore`, and then throws the error

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file './data': Permission denied
```

Comment: Have you tried `tools::showNonASCII` and `tools::showNonASCIIfile`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – the problem is that there are a lot of files that could potentially harbour the errant character. It will take a long time to enter their names manually.

Comment: Perhaps, you could test all your `Rd` files using a loop based off `list.files` and `tools::showNonASCIIfile`.