# Check for non-latin characters with REGEXMATCH for Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, re2

I tried to make a formula which just have to return TRUE | FALSE if a cell contains one or more non-latin characters and tried something like this, but failed - it's always TRUE ([found nothing here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20%5Bregex%5D%20latin)):

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2; "[[:^alpha:]]+")
```

Some examples of data:

- daocao@yahoo.com - there are no non-latin characters
- huynhbaoquóqdq@gmail.com - there is a non-latin character

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)

Comment: Great! It works, thanks! Is it possible to mark this question as a duplicate or something similar?

Comment: Nice. My comment was auto-generated because I casted a close-vote (duplicate) on your post. It takes 3 votes to close it or I believe you can accept the closure early if you are presented with a button which says "Yes, this solved my issue"

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "[^A-Za-z@.]"))="")
```

[image: 0]

or `TRUE`/`FALSE` reverted:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "[^A-Za-z@.]"))<>"")
```