# QValidator for ASCII characters stays invalid

Tags: python, regex, pyside2, qvalidator

I am trying to build a lineEdit that checks for non-ascii characters.
I tested the RegEx using regex101 and it worked as expected.`[:ascii:]` seems to be a PCRE and should therefore work with the QtRegExp, right?
However, my QValidator subclass always returns `QValidator.State.Invalid` (unless the lineEdit is empty when it returns `QValidator.State.Intermediate`) even when the the lineEdit clearly contains ASCII chars only.

Here is the code for the validator:

```
class ASCIIValidator (QtGui.QRegExpValidator):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ASCIIValidator, self).__init__()
        self.ASCII_REGEXP = QtCore.QRegExp()
        self.ASCII_REGEXP.setPattern(r'^[[:ascii:]]+$')
        self.ASCII_REGEXP.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setRegExp(self.ASCII_REGEXP)
```

And here is my custom lineEdit:

```
class ULineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    focusChange = QtCore.Signal(bool)
    validated = QtCore.Signal(QtGui.QValidator.State)

    """Custom lineedit"""
    def __init__(self,
            defaultText: str = "",
            validators: list = [],
            completer: QtWidgets.QCompleter = None):

        super(ULineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.setText(defaultText)
        if completer is not None and isinstance(completer, QtWidgets.QCompleter):
            self.setCompleter(completer)
        self.validators = validators
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        # Signals
        self.textChanged.connect(self.validateText)

    def addValidator(self, validator: QtGui.QValidator):
        if isinstance(validator, QtGui.QValidator):
            self.validators.append(validator)
            return
        elif isinstance(validator, list):
            self.validators.extend(validator)
            return

    def validateText(self):
        """Check validators and set the style"""
        if len(self.validators) > 0:
            for val in self.validators:
                testResult = val.validate(self.text(), 0)[0] #validate() returns a tuple
                invalidTests = []
                intermedTests = []
                acceptedTests = []
                print(testResult)
                if testResult == QtGui.QValidator.Invalid:
                    invalidTests.append(testResult)
                elif testResult == QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate:
                    intermedTests.append(testResult)
                elif testResult == QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable:
                    acceptedTests.append(testResult)
            if len(invalidTests) > 0:
                self.setStyleSheet(INVALID_STYLESHEET)
                self.validated.emit(QtGui.QValidator.Invalid)
                return QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
            
            if len(intermedTests) > 0: 
                self.setStyleSheet(LINEEDIT_STYLESHEET)
                self.validated.emit(QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate)
                return QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate

            if len(acceptedTests) > 0:
                self.setStyleSheet(VALID_STYLESHEET)
                self.validated.emit(QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable)
                return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the range of ASCII characters to validate whether or not it is as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124144/6622587):

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ASCIIValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        pattern = r"[^\x00-\x7F]+$"
        regex = QtCore.QRegExp(pattern)
        regex.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setRegExp(regex)


class JoinValidator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._validators = []

    @property
    def validators(self):
        return self._validators

    def add_validator(self, validator):
        self.validators.append(validator)

    def validate(self, _input, pos):
        texts = []
        positions = []
        final_state = QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable
        for validator in self.validators:
            state, new_input, new_pos = validator.validate(_input, pos)
            texts.append(new_input)
            positions.append(new_pos)
            if state == QtGui.QValidator.Invalid:
                final_state = QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
            elif (
                state == QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate
                and final_state != QtGui.QValidator.Invalid
            ):
                final_state = QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate
        new_pos = min(positions)
        new_input = min(texts, key=len)
        return final_state, new_input, new_pos


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.lineedit)

        self.validator = JoinValidator()
        self.validator.add_validator(ASCIIValidator())

        self.lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.handle_text_changed)

    def handle_text_changed(self):
        state, _, _ = self.validator.validate(
            self.lineedit.text(), self.lineedit.cursorPosition()
        )
        print(state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have you tested the code? Because when I follow your implementation, I still get the behaviour described in my original post. Always returns State.Invalid unless the lineedit is empty.The concept of a JoinValidator was a good tip though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with r"[^\\x00-\\x7F]+$" instead of r"[^\x00-\x7F]+$" (with double back slash) ? It works in C++.