# javascript string replace &lt; into <

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Hey all, I basically output content into a div like this using jquery:

```
var text = $("#edit").val();
$("#output").text(text);
```

But I want to turn "&lt;" and "&gt;" into "<" and ">".

`text.replace(/&lt;/,"<");` doesn't seem to be working for me...

Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: Could you use .html(text) instead of .text(text)?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else? If I type in chrome console `"abcde&lt;hey&gt;dfdfgf".replace(/&lt;/g,"<").replace(/&gt;/g,">")` I get the correct answer...

Comment: @Peter: afraid not, I want "<" as TEXT not as html..

Comment: mostly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513112/setting-nodevalue-of-text-node-in-javascript-when-string-contains-html-entities

Comment: I know. HTML interprets &lt; and &gt; as text.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simple.

```
var needToConvert = 'But I want to turn "&lt;" and "&gt;" into "<" and ">".';

var convert = function(convert){
    return $("<span />", { html: convert }).text();
    //return document.createElement("span").innerText;
};

alert(convert(needToConvert));
```

Comment: @mdlars Could you be more specific? I just tried it, and it still works.

Answer (score 27):

You could use something like the [`unescapeHTML()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/unescapeHTML) function in prototype...

Adapted from [prototype js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) source

```
function unescapeHTML(escapedHTML) {
  return escapedHTML.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&amp;/g,'&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign it to variable:

```
var text = $("#edit").val();
text = text.replace("&lt;","<");
```

this will work fine

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence, others are ignored

Answer (score 0):

You need use .html() Because text() converts all html tags

```
$("#output").html(text);
```