# JavaScript replace <br> with \n

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have just stored a paragraph of text in a MySQL database using JavaScript and PHP and replaced `\n` with `<br />`, the problem I'm now having is when I try and retrieve the text using PHP it prints it out as; `<br />`

```
Dear Sir/Maddam<br />This is a letter concerning the following;<br />I would like to....
```

Comment: Why can't you just reverse what you did when you added it?

Comment: Why did you even alter text before storage? 
Why not modifying it only before display?

Comment: You should better store simple text without markup in the database. Web page is a view, so converting of `\n` to `<br />` should be better done on print out.

Comment: Has the data been stored as html characters as opposed to literals? I.e. Are `<` stored as `&lt;` ... If so use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5302086/94278

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the obvious solution is to just not replace `\n` with `<br />` in the first place.

I don't know what language you're trying to reverse the damage in...

```
// PHP:
$out = preg_replace("/<br ?\/?>/i","\n",$in);

// JS:
out = input.replace(/<br ?\/?>/ig,"\n");
```

Comment: It was a just typo not a reason for downvoting!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply remove those characters in your PHP you could use the handy [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function. This however will remove **all** HMTL elements in your string.

If you want to simply convert the `<br/>` string back to a `\n` then you can use php's [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

```
$newString = str_replace("<br/>", "\n", $originalString);
```

Comment: It might be a typo, but in the OP's question `<br />` (with space) is used.

Comment: @jas - That is just how I am used to writing `<br/>`.  If the problem is that the OP can't just copy paste my code... then that is acceptable by me. I'm not writing code for anyone - I'm simply explaining  what I would do.

Comment: Hehe. True. Anyhow, I would prefer this kind of replacement over using regular expressions. +1