# replaceAll <BR> with \n

Tags: java, regex, replace, replaceall

I am not very good in the ways of Regex; therefor I am here to get help.

I am working in Java atm.

What I am looking for is a piece of code, that goes through a String and uses replaceAll()

```
The tags I want to change from and to:
replaceAll() : <BR>, <br>, <br /> or/and <BR /> with “\n”
```

What I have tried to do, is the following from this
[JavaScript replace `<br>` with `\n` link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12461914/3430698)
but from debugging, I can see that it, doesn’t change the String.

**MyCode**

```
String titleName = model.getText();

// this Gives me the string comprised of different values, all Strings.

countryName<BR> dateFrom - dateTo: - \n hotelName <br />

// for easy overview I have created to variables, with the following values

String patternRegex = "/<br ?\\/?>/ig";
String newline = "\n";
```

With these two, I now create my titleNameRegex string, with the titleName String.

```
String titleNameRegex = titleName.replaceAll(patternRegex, newline);
```

I have had a look at [Java regex replaceAll multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154300/3430698) as well, because of the need to be case insensitive, but unsure where to put the flag for this and is it `(?i)` ?

So what I am looking for, is that my regex code should, replaceAll `<BR>` and `<br />` with `\n`,
so that i looks properly in my PDF document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/<br ?\\/?>/ig` is Javascript regex syntax, in Java you need to use:

```
String patternRegex = "(?i)<br */?>";
```

`(?i)` is for ignore case comparison.

Comment: So what I have written in Javascript regex, is the same as what you have written in Java regex?

Comment: Yes definitely it is same and much simpler than the answer you've marked as accepted. [You can see this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK8sB3/1)

Answer (score 1):

I really hate regexp this is an alien language. But what you are trying to do is :

- Look (case insensitive) for a `"<br"` string, done like that : `(?i)<br`
- After this string find zero or more space, done like that : `\\p{javaSpaceChar}*`
- After the spaces find either `>` or `/>`, done like that : `(?:/>|>)`

So your final regexp in java is :

```
String titleName = "countryName<BR/> dateFrom <Br    >- dateTo: - <br/> hotelName <br  />";
String patternRegex = "(?i)<br\\p{javaSpaceChar}*(?:/>|>)";
String newline = "\n";
String titleNameRegex = titleName.replaceAll(patternRegex, newline);
```

I added some mixed case + more than 1 space to show all cases.