# Rendering mySQL string as HTML in Bootstrap Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this has been asked before. I couldn't find anything that resolved this issue for me.

I have Google Maps API pulling data from a mySQL database via PHP. 
The results are plotted on the map as markers.

From there, I am using Bootstrap to display a modal window when a marker is clicked. The content of the modal is coming dynamically from the database.

Everything is working fine EXCEPT one of the database fields is populated with a HTML string coming from a rich text input. Something simple like this:

```
<b>this is bold text</b>
```

When I put this string directly into my javascript listener like this:

```
$('.modal-body').html('<b>this is bold text</b>');
```

the HTML is parsed fine and I get the expected output with bold text and no visible tags.

But when I use the string queried from the database like this:

```
$('.modal-body').html(content);
```

it is displayed as raw text with tags showing and no formatting.

This is the test page I am working with http://www.toyonder.com/mapTest/mapTest.html

Any ideas how I would go about getting the queried string to render as HTML?

Comment: Sounds to me like you've HTML encoded your data (via `htmlspecialchars()`) before inserting or after selecting it from your database. We'll need to see the code (PHP and JavaScript) that populates your `content` variable before being able to answer this properly.

Comment: Having a look at the XML returned by your `phpsqlajax_genxml2.php` script, I can see that the `content` parameters are indeed HTML encoded, ie `content="&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;This is Bold Text&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;"`. Quick question, why XML?

Comment: Hi Phil. I'm learning as I go here. Using a lot of sample code I've found about the place and modifying it to fit my requirements. XML is how the example worked, so XML is what I ended up with. Is there a better alternative for the Maps API? I was under the impression XML with custom attributes was the only way to go. Definitely open to suggestions though.

Comment: Also probably worth noting that the HTML strings have currently been manually input as I haven't got around to the rich text form input yet. So within the database they look exactly the same as the way they are being output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you have `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`.

Try this

```
$('.modal-body').html($("<span />", { html: content }).text());
```

This will convert the content to html, and then back to text, and finally back to html for the modal-body.

I must also reference this question, because it is where I learned this method: [javascript string replace &lt; into <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302037/javascript-string-replace-lt-into)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. In the database the string has < and >, not &lt; and &gt; - so the encoding must be happening somewhere in the PHP or javascript, yeah?

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks so much for your help!!