# Add &nbsp; to Non-tagged HTML Text in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument, html-manipulation

I have this kind of HTML document.

```
<span class="class1">text1</span>
<a href="">link1</a>
<font color=""><b>text2</b></font>
<a href="">link2</a>
text3
<span class="class2">text4</span>
```

And I'd like to surround text1, text2 and text3 by `&nbsp;`s. What would be the best way? DomDocument cannot catch strings that are not tagged. For text1 and text2,  `getElementByTagName('tagname')->item(0)` can be used but for text 3, I'm not sure what to do.

Any ideas?

[Edit]

As Musa suggests, I tried using nextSibling.

```
<?php
$html = <<<STR
    <span class="class1">text1</span>
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <font color=""><b>text2</b></font>
    <a href="">link2</a>
    text3
    <span class="class2">text4</span>
STR;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $nodeA) {
    $nodeA->nextSibling->nodeValue = '&nbsp;' . $nodeA->nextSibling->nodeValue . '&nbsp;';
}
echo $doc->saveHtml();
?>
```

However, `&nbsp;`gets escaped and converted to `&amp;nbsp;`

Comment: How about `getElementByTagName('a')[1].nextSibling`

Comment: As the engine appears to be escaping characters for you, can you instead append a blank space before and after the node. The engine may then convert it to `&nbsp;` for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It just adds white spaces in the source, not in the displayed page.

Comment: Bummer - does answer for this help at all? js I know, but seems to be the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513112/setting-nodevalue-of-text-node-in-javascript-when-string-contains-html-entities

Comment: I posted one solution by myself. But it does not look elegant. So I'm still looking for a way. Of course in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the setting the value seems to set it as text and not html you could use the non-breaking space character instead of the html entity.

```
<?php
$html = <<<STR
    <span class="class1">text1</span>
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <font color=""><b>text2</b></font>
    <a href="">link2</a>
    text3
    <span class="class2">text4</span>
STR;
$nbsp = "\xc2\xa0";
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>');

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes as $node ) {
    if ($node->nodeType == 3) {     // nodeType:3 TEXT_NODE
        $node->nodeValue = $nbsp . $node->nodeValue . $nbsp;
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHtml();
?>
```

Comment: I get backticks instead of white spaces.

Comment: @Teno I had `"\xc1\xa0"` it suppose to be `"\xc2\xa0"`

Comment: `$nbsp = "\xc2\xa0";` help me alot.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `getElementsByTagName` and then iterate over the node list, adding `&nbsp;` as necessary.

```
getElementsByTagName('body')
```

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

will return a `nodelist`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php

which you can then iterate over the individual items

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

the nodeType will let you know what you are dealing with. Text3 is a TEXT_NODE which has a value of `3`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nodeType

Hope that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'll see if I can understand them to use.

Comment: I'm still hoping some working examples as my attempt in the updated post does not work. I tried overwriting the nodeValue but the character gets escaped.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with:

```
<?php
$html = <<<STR
    <span class="class1">text1</span>
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <font color=""><b>text2</b></font>
    <a href="">link2</a>
    text3
    <span class="class2">text4</span>
STR;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>');

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes as $node ) {
    if ($node->nodeType == 3) {     // nodeType:3 TEXT_NODE
        $node->nodeValue = '[identical_replacement_string]' . $node->nodeValue . '[identical_replacement_string]';
    }
}
$output = str_replace("[identical_replacement_string]", "&nbsp;", $doc->saveHtml());
echo $output;
?>
```

Please feel free to post better solutions.