# Remove specific HTML tags and non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, html, string

How can I remove <table>, <tr>, and <td> HTML tags plus non-ASCII characters from a string using C#?

I want to leave other tags in the string alone.

Comment: Examples of input with desired output greatly help this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these questions:

[Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

[How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I want only remove <table>,<tr>,<td> type tag not styling tag.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Google search: http://en.csharp-online.net/Strip_all_HTML_tags

Comment: I want only remove <table>,<tr>,<td> type tag not styling tag.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. At the time I answered, the question was not how to removed specific tags only. If you change your question after you received anwers it's no surprise the answers won't fit anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you want to do this, I'd recommend against trying.  There are many pitfalls, even with Regex.

Personally I'd recommend encoding the input, rather than trying to strip stuff out of it.

Comment: I want only remove <table>,<tr>,<td> type tag not styling tag.