# How to remove all non - ASCII characters from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I seems to be a very simple and much needed method. I need to remove all non ASCII characters from a string. e.g Â© etc. See the following example.

```
#coding: utf-8
s = " Hello this a mixed string Â© that I made."
puts s.encoding
puts s.encode
```

output:

```
UTF-8
Hello this a mixed str
```

ing ┬⌐ that I made.

When I feed this to Watir, it produces following error:incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

So my problem is that I want to get rid of all non ASCII characters before using it. I will not know which encoding the source string "s" uses.

I have been searching and experimenting for quite some time now.

If I try to use

```
  puts s.encode('ASCII-8BIT')
```

It gives the error:

```
 : "\xC2\xA9" from UTF-8 to ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

Answer (score 43):

You can just literally translate what you asked into a `Regexp`. You wrote:

> I want to get rid of all non ASCII characters

We can rephrase that a little bit:

> I want to substitue all characters which don't thave the `ASCII` property with nothing

And that's a statement that can be *directly* expressed in a `Regexp`:

```
s.gsub!(/\P{ASCII}/, '')
```

As an alternative, you could also use `String#delete!`:

```
s.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}")
```

Comment: 1000.times { puts "6 out of 5 stars" }  -- This saved my bacon Jörg. Thank you for educating me by proxy.

Comment: for the `{ASCII}` one I get `Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)` on ruby 1.9.3

Comment: for ruby 1.9,.3 you need to use delete, not the {ASCII} approach

Comment: This `s.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}")` saved me from the misery!!!  Thank you very so much.

Answer (score 2):

Strip out the characters using regex. This example is in C# but the regex should be the same:
[How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Translating it into ruby using gsub should not be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding.  When a character occupies one byte, its value coincides with 7-bit ASCII.  So why don't you just look for bytes with a '1' in the MSB, and then remove both them and their trailers?  A byte beginning with '110' will be followed by one additional byte.  A byte beginning with '1110' will be followed by two.  And a byte beginning with '11110' will be followed by three, the maximum supported by UTF-8.

This is all just off the top of my head.  I could be wrong.