# How to remove non-ASCII word from a string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to filter some string which has some wrong letters (non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)). It looks different in Notepad, Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL.

How can I check if a string has non-ASCII letters and how I can remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to filter non ASCII characters:

```
string input = "AB £ CD";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[^\x0d\x0a\x20-\x7e\t]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions.

```
Regex.Replace(input, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")
```

You could also use `\W+` as the pattern to remove any non-character.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a God-send:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", "");
```

I think I got it elsewhere originally, but here is a link to the same answer here:

[How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
string testString = Regex.Replace(OldString, @"[\u0000-\u0008\u000A-\u001F\u0100-\uFFFF]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to determine what you mean by a "word". If non-ascii, this probably implies non-english?

Personally, I'd ask why you need to do this and what fundamental assumption has your application got that conflicts with your data? Depending on the situation, I suggest you either re-encode the text from the source encoding, although this will be a lossy conversion, or alternatively, address that fundamental assumption so that your application handles data correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I think something as simple as this would probably work, wouldn't it?

```
public static string AsciiOnly(this string input, bool includeExtendedAscii)
{
    int upperLimit = includeExtendedAscii ? 255 : 127;
    char[] asciiChars = input.Where(c => (int)c <= upperLimit).ToArray();
    return new string(asciiChars);
}
```

Example usage:

```
string input = "AB£ȼCD";
string asciiOnly = input.AsciiOnly(false); // returns "ABCD"
string extendedAsciiOnly = input.AsciiOnly(true); // returns "AB£CD"
```

Comment: Firstly, what's "extended ascii"? Secondly, I can't see how this works unless you assume UTF-8 encoding? Certainly not the default UTF-16 encoding because then the results won't fit in a char array? (Char's are 8-bit, right?)