# Replace symbols from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can we replace symbols from string in C#?

Like this

Input : `"�Click me."`

Output: `"Click me."`;

Comment: How did you get such symbols in the first place? Looks like you have crapped encoding. Replacing is not a solution. Tackle the problem at its roots which is: fix the way you are getting this string and don't try to resuscitate a dead thing.

Comment: Looks like an [encoding/codepage issue](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Are you just trying to remove everything but alphanumeric and punctuation?

Comment: @Darin: Wont ALT + give all such symbols? :) lets assume he has to deal with all that.

Comment: @yetanothercoder, that's something that should have been mentioned in the question. Usually when people ask a question on StackOverflow it is considered good practice to describe their scenario. Unfortunately this isn't the case with this question.

Comment: @Darin: always respected you wisdom. its something called novice :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simplistic solution would be to strip all non-ASCII characters from your string. There are a couple of ways to do this available on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c), the simplest of which would probably be:

```
string s = "�Click me.";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", "");
```

Although as mentioned, this may be an encoding/codepage issue -- using a regex here may not necessarily be the appropriate solution.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments, here are a couple other patterns you can try:

Remove all non-ASCII characters and ASCII control characters:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0020-\u007F]", "");
```

Remove everything except for alphanumeric ASCII characters:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: when I try write xml after replacing non-ascii characters then still I am getting this error "hexadecimal value 0x05 is invalid character"

Comment: @Novice `0x05` is an ASCII control character. If you wanted to remove those as well, you could use this instead of what's posted in my answer: `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0020-\u007F]", "");`. Where are you getting your input from?

Comment: I am getting input from mysql database. Field characterset in table is "utf_8"

Comment: @Novice Try using the second code snippet I posted in my comment, does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Donut Yes, it has solved issue partially now when it replaces another input string then it throws error again "0X1C is invalid character". Can we replace all characters instead of a-z A-Z 0-9 ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Novice Updated my answer with another pattern that you can try that should replace all non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @Donut I've tried but unfortunately still its throwing an error "0x1C is an invalid hexadecimal character"

Answer (score 3):

```
var output = input.Replace("�","");
```

Simples!

Comment: Yeah, but `�` is what you see on the screen, the actual value is probably something else so this replace won't likely do much.

Comment: Oh totally, I just answered the question directly - "How can we replace symbols from string in C#"

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: It surely would remove � thought? It is a character *somewhere* after all

Comment: @ Kurru, of course, it's just that I doubt very much that the actual character to be replaced here is �.

Comment: @HansPassant: The question-mark-in-diamond symbol represents the Unicode Replacement Character, [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).  It's what the decoder generates when it finds a byte pattern that's invalid for the current encoding.  A character that's not supported by the current font usually appears as a simple rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use unicode block names:

```
source = Regex.Replace(source , @"\p{name}", "");
```

A list of names can be found in [this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks)  I'm not sure what block your character would belong to though.