# Regex to remove non-URL friendly characters, but allow Unicode and accents

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

I have the following regex:

```
foo = Regex.Replace(foo, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]", " ");
```

Currently, this removes Unicode characters. What regex can I use remove all non-URL friendly characters (i.e. : , < etc.), but **allow** Unicode and accented characters?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Could you give us a complete list of what characters you consider "non-URL friendly"? Why should f.i. "less than" be unfriendly?

Comment: I dont know if this helps but could you use the htmlencode?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx. This should make all the necessary replacements for you.

Comment: Sorry there is also an equivelant for URL encoding... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: I don't actually want to HTML Encode it because it's being used to construct yet another URL. The variable 'foo' is actually a search term, so I just need to explicitly yank anything that's not URL-friendly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Unicode character"?

Comment: Technically, even the characters that you want to remove are Unicode characters (in a loose sense of the word "character"). Do you mean everything that is not ASCII?

Comment: I want to remove from the input string everything that is not "safe" user input in any language. Giving this problem another look, I may want to just use Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.GetSafeHtml().

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.GetSafeHtml()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

How about instead of using a negated class, you simply have a replacement list of the characters you dont want?

```
s/[:,<]*//g
```

Comment: I was looking for something a little less specific than those three characters lol

Comment: Is that really justification to downvote the question? I'm sorry this isn't what you wanted, but that wasn't specified in the question either. A simple comment would have sufficed.