# Special letters check

Tags: c#, char, special-characters

How can I check if a `TextBox` contains numbers, letters, and also have special letters like "õ, ä, ö, ü"?

I use code to check numbers and letters:

```
Regex.IsMatch(Value, "^[a-z0-9]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: A better question is what characters do you WANT to exclude?

Comment: To check for specific unicode chars in Regex you can use `\unnnn` predicatem where nnnn is char code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does **[How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c)** contain any pointers?

You could include the unicode using the `\uXXXX` syntax within the regex for any additional letters you specifically want to strip test for.

```
Regex.IsMatch(Value, "^[a-z0-9\u00c0-\u00f6]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: But I don't get, why this doesn't work with "^" infront. When i remove it, it works fine..

Answer (score 8):

> How can I check if textbox contains numbers and letters only,

```
bool isValid = textBox.Text.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

Consider the following example:

```
string str = "Something123õäö";
bool isValid = str.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

You will get `true` for the above case.

Comment: what if he wants to include not all of the `char.IsLetterOrDigit` characters, e.g. "ä" and "ö" but not "õ"?

Comment: This answer depends on the unicode normalization of the string! For example `"olé".Normalize()` will be okay, while `"ole\u0301"` or `"olé".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)` will be rejected. Note that some (rare) accented letters can not be made with one `System.Char` code unit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got easier method for my code down below :)

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over every char and compare with or to the other chars and with [`char.GetUnicodeCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getunicodecategory.aspx) for letters and digits:

```
var allowed = new[] { 'ö', 'ä' };
var isOK = textBox1.Text.All(c =>
    char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter ||
    char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter ||
    char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber ||
    allowed.Contains(c));
```

`UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter` are standard lowercase letters (`'a'..'z'`), `UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter` are uppercase letters, and `UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber` are digits, so this and a customized `allowed` array should take care of everything you want to accept.

Comment: This code gets really long, got shorter code down below, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate all "word charters" just use `\w` if you want to see if a whole string is just word characters or digits use the regex `^(\w|\d)+$`

Comment: I give a try for this also, but got my problem solved by code above :)