# In C#, how can I detect if a character is a non-ASCII character?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char, ascii

I would like to check, in C#, if a char contains a non-ASCII character. What is the best way to check for special characters such as `志` or `Ω`?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bcdfb967-aa97-4d26-9daa-d20829f805b9/detect-nonascii-characters

Comment: you can also use regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 52, accepted):

ASCII ranges from 0 - 127, so just check for that range:

```
char c = 'a';//or whatever char you have
bool isAscii = c < 128;
```

Comment: And for those who want to be fancy, `bool isAscii = c <= sbyte.MaxValue;`.

Answer (score 58):

```
bool HasNonASCIIChars(string str)
{
    return (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str) != str.Length);
}
```

Comment: Now that's an interesting way to go about this. Really clever!

Answer (score 13):

Just in case anybody comes across this. In dotNET6 there is a [new method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isascii?view=net-6.0) to check whether a character is an ASCII character or not

```cs
public static bool IsAscii (char c);
```

To solve the issue, you can just write

```cs
var containsOnlyAscii = str.All(char.IsAscii);
```

using the [LINQ `All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0) method.

---

In general, you can use this new method to check individual characters

```cs
var isAscii = char.IsAscii(c);
```