# Validation Rule for checking if text has only ASCII

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, ascii

How can I validate one Textbox so that it only contains ASCII characters?

```
<TextBox Name="PbnameText" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="False" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I tried to add a ValidationRule, but it needs always to implement Min and Max properties

```
public class NameRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (true)
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"Illegal characters or {e.Message}");
        else
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a character is an ASCII-character is [quite easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596245/in-c-how-can-i-detect-if-a-character-is-a-non-ascii-character) actually.

It looks like you took the code from the example class in the [.NET docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationrule?view=netframework-4.8). The class there is for validating an age range, so it's going to need the `Min` and `Max` properties, but you don't need them and a validation rule certaintly doesn't *always* need to implement them, so you can safely remove them.

The validation rule can look something like this (C# 7 or later):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class NameRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return value is string str && str.All(ch => ch < 128)
            ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
            : new ValidationResult(false, "The name contains illegal characters");
    }
}
```

The `ch < 128` part is the ASCII check.

You also need to specify that you want to use the rule in your binding (supposing that your rule lives in the `c` XAML namespace).

```
<TextBox Name="PbnameText" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="False">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <c:NameRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

You can find more information on data binding validation [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframework-4.8).