# Reading from a text file with some really weird string length results

Tags: string, text, streamreader

I'm trying to read a text file full of Twitter Screen Names and store them in a database. ScreenNames can't be more than 15 characters so one of my checks ensures that the name isn't more than 15 characters.

I've found something really strange going on when I try to upload AmericanExpress.

This is my text file contents:

```
americanexpress
AmericanExpress‎
AMERICANEXPRESS
```

And this is my code:

```
var names = new List<string>();
var badNames = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        var name = line.ToLower().Trim();

        Debug.WriteLine(line + " " + line.Length + " " + name + " " + name.Length);
        if (name.Length > 15 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            badNames.Add(name);
            continue;
        }

        if (names.Contains(name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        names.Add(name);
    }
}
```

The first americanexpress passes the under 15 length test, the second fails, and the third passes. When I debug the code and hover over name during the second loop for AmericanExpress, this is what I get:

[image]
[image]

And this is Debug output:

```
americanexpress 15 americanexpress 15
AmericanExpress‎ 16 americanexpress‎ 16
AMERICANEXPRESS 15 americanexpress 15
```

I've counted the characters in AmericanExpress at least 10 times, and I'm pretty sure it's only 15 character.

Does anyone have any idea why Visual Studio is telling me americanexpress.Length = 16?

SOLUTION

name = Regex.Replace(name, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);

Comment: Is it test data you created or did you get it from somewhere? There can be zero-width UTF character inside text, not visible, but most certainly calculated into width of a word. Also - some letters can be utf characters looking like normal letters. I'm pretty sure c# string will calculate them as one character, but it's worth checking if that's the case

Comment: It's data I've been given. AmericanExpress I copy pasted to my text file and the others I added. When I deleted AmericanExpress and wrote it myself it was down to 15 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the s is a character, which is not visible but counts as a char.
look at

```
name[15]    8206 '‎'
```

for information about the char 8206 see
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm

possible solution:
read only the ASCII values

```
var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line.ToLower().Trim()));
```

Comment: Yep that's the one! But changing it to ASCII I get this: "AmericanExpress???". I just found the solution to removing it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123336/how-can-you-strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-c

Comment: Good to hear you fixed you're problem

Comment: Yeh thought I might be going a little crazy for a while. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.